# Javascript Execution Question

Tags: javascript

If I have an event that runs multiple javascripts does the following script wait until the previous script is complete before it runs?

Example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:SCRIPT_1();SCRIPT_2();SCRIPT_3();">Test Me</a>
```

Will `SCRIPT_2` not execute until `SCRIPT_1` is complete doing its stuff?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, yes, javascript execution is synchronous. So, `SCRIPT_2` will not execute untill `SCRIPT_1` is done.

**edit** Yep, the accepted answer on [when-is-javascript-synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous) is worth a read

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. Javascript is executed synchronously so `SCRIPT_1` will complete before `SCRIPT_2` begins (at least when defined like you have).