# Javascript Array undefined?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This seems like a ridiculously trivial issue but I can't solve it.

I have this function. `var q` is assigned to an array of strings. `alert(q)` successfully prints the entire array when the function is called.

```
function initQuestions() {
    $.post("quiz.php", { 'func': 'load' }, function(data) {
        var q = data.split(".\n");
        alert(q);
        return q;
    });
}
```

However, when I attempt to use the function (as depicted below in 2 ways) I am told the array is undefined. Why is this the case?

```
var questions;

$(function() {
    //This doesn't work
    questions = initQuestions();
    alert(questions);

    //Neither does this
    alert(initQuestions());
});
```

Upon further research I added a callback to `initQuestions()` but am having the same result.

Comment: don't try to alert it, instead use `console.log()`

Comment: check the error log in your browser. you have it for a reason. and use console.log instead of alert.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of asynchronous web programming

Comment: You are reading the value before var q get set.

Comment: thats a scope issue by the looks of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post call is asynchronous: [Async Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104474/how-does-asynchronous-javascript-execution-happen-and-when-not-to-use-return-st)

Basically, the initQuestions() function returns `null` before the `post` finishes

Thinks of it like this:

```
function initQuestions() {
    $.post("quiz.php", { 'func': 'load' }, function(data) {
        var q = data.split(".\n");
        alert(q);
        return q; // <- returns to the caller of function(data), not initQuestions()!
    });
    return null; // <- This happens before function(data) is complete
}
```

To make it work as expected, you need to supply a callback for when the post is successful and finishes.

```
function initQuestions(callback) {
    $.post("quiz.php", { 'func': 'load' }, function(data) {
        var q = data.split(".\n");
        alert(q);
        callback(q);
    });
}

var questions;

function doSomthingWithQuestions() {
    alert(questions); // <- should work
    // do the things with the questions
}

$(function() {
    initQuestions(function(result) {
       questions = result;
       doSomethingWithQuestions();
    });

    // Don't use `questions` here as the callback hasn't fired yet. 
});
```

Comment: This explains why it doesn't work, but not what the OP should do about it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but it''s something I tried previously to no avail. What made it work this time round was placing the function call at the very top of document.ready. Why does it happen that a piece of code won't work when placed after an unrelated piece of other code?

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon. `questions` is still undefined outside of the callback

Comment: It will be if you're calling code outside of the callback before the callback has fired.  If you want to use the questions variable, you have to use it *after* the questions are loaded

Answer (score 0):

The post is asynchronous, return doesnt go to the function you expect, but to the success handler:

```
function initQuestions() {
  $.post("quiz.php", { 'func': 'load' }, function(data) { // <- this function has that return
    var q = data.split(".\n");
    alert(q);
    return q;
  });
}
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re) is how to supress asynchronous behaviour and achive what you want

**EDIT:**

As some people said here, `asych = false` is a bad idea since it freezes you JS code until the request is done (can take seconds with slow connection), so solution would be to do whatever you want in the success function:

```
questions = initQuestions(); //wrong
fillDivsWithData(questions); //use callback instead:

function initQuestions() {
  $.post("quiz.php", { 'func': 'load' }, function(data) {
    var q = data.split(".\n");
    console.log(q); //diplay this in you browser's JS console
    fillDivsWithData(q);
  });
}
```

result is same, but thanks to asynch request your JS code doesnt freeze for seconds if you have potatoe internet connection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests maybe even better example (duplicate in fact)

Answer (score 0):

```
var questions; // undefined right now
initQuestions(function(_questions){
  questions = _questions; // the value has been set thanks to the anonymous function you passed as the callback
})

function initQuestions(callback  // this is a callback function reference) {

  // This HTTP Post call takes time to complete and is done asynchronously
  $.post("quiz.php", { 'func': 'load' }, function(data) {
    var q = data.split(".\n");
    // Luckily your initQuestions now takes in a callback function
    // You have access to the callback function here and when ready you can use it
    callback(q);
  });
  // JavaScript engine doesn't wait for your HTTP call to complete 
  // and will continue to execute the function
  // In this case, your function isn't returning anything hence undefined

}
```

Comment: asynch = false, that solves this problem, this solution is needlessly complicated

Comment: This indicates that asynch = false shouldn't be used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @kajacx - async false is `bad` for the user experience and a bad, bad design decision (it locks up the browser UI during the ajax call).  It should pretty much never be used.

Comment: Yea, that lock up is bad, but OP asked how his initQuestions() function can return data from ajax, and that cant be done otherwise then by asynch=false

Comment: "Why is this the case?" was the question.