# How to change global var value from local scope in express Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Check this piece of code

```
            var self = this;
            var flag = true;

            UserSessionModel.setDB(req.db);
            UserSessionModel.checkIdandToken(req.headers, function(err, result) {
               if(result.length == 0){
                  console.log(flag); // prints TRUE in console
                  flag = false;
                  res.status(400).send(self.createResponse({}, {
                     success : false,
                     message : "User Id or Token is invalid"
                  }));
              }
           });

           console.log(flag); // prints TRUE in console
```

At the last line, it should be FALSE.
Please Guide Me

Comment: It's `true` because of "asynchronicity" – I'm pretty sure the second argument of your `checkIdandToken` is a callback function. You `console.log` is executed before that code is run.

Comment: Great I got your point. can you please suggest me what can I do to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I've mentioned in my comment, it's `true` because of "asynchronicity" – I'm pretty sure the second argument of your `checkIdandToken` is a callback function. You `console.log` is executed before that code is run.

Essentially you variable is changed, but after you run the `console.log`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104474/how-does-asynchronous-javascript-execution-happen-and-when-not-to-use-return-st) explains how asynchronous code works.

Comment: Great I got your point. can you please suggest me what can I do to overcome this problem.

Comment: If you put your `console.log` inside your callback function, it will show the correct (expected) value. Essentially all the code you want to run after the flag is set to true needs to be within the callback function, otherwise it gets executed before the flag is set.