# Order of execution confusing

Tags: javascript, html, parseint

This is the code I'm using to get the client width as a JavaScript whole number variable so that I can perform operations on it.

```
var width1;
window.onload = function()
{
    width1 = document.body.clientWidth;
}
var width = parseInt(width1);
```

The variable width is return `NaN`.

Comment: yes it is, because window.onload doesn't execute until the document is loaded, but the parseInt is run immediately

Comment: Ok, I added the onload because the client width was not registering (says undefined) without it, is there a workaround?

Comment: I wouldn't say there's a workaround except to change how you program knowing that not everything is synchronous, and knowing when something is asynchronous is a big advantage

Comment: Asynchronous, asynchronous, asynchronous.  After you do some research on your own for what an asynchronous callback is and when it is called, you will understand much better why your code executes in the order it does.  This is one of the first advanced concepts one must learn to write Javascript in a browser.

Comment: The workaround is to put everything inside `window.onload`. If that feels strange don't worry, it's perfectly normal in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written isn't executed top to bottom, waiting for functions to be executed that are defined - the function assigned to `window.onload` is deferred until that event is satisfied, that is the, window has loaded.

Any post-processing of that value *needs* to happen in that callback too.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var width = parseInt(document.body.clientWidth);
    // Now do your work with `width` here.
}
```

[Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104474/how-does-asynchronous-javascript-execution-happen-and-when-not-to-use-return-st)

Also, the brace style you're using isn't recommended in JavaScript, as some parts of the language don't function as you may intend if you use it to return an object literal, for example.

```
return 
{
    prop: 'value'
}
```

The grammar says there can't be a line terminator after `return`, so you would get the standard `return undefined` behaviour, with an orphaned object literal.

Comment: The code **is** executed top down! Otherwise, yeah, all good. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Yeah, it's hard to explain that. What I meant is that if the interpreter sees a function assigned somewhere, it's not gonna halt and wait for it to be executed. :D