# Where do I find my dbname for MongoDB connection string?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect my app to mongodb, and I got a connection string from mongodb atlas, requiring me to replace username and password, which I get it, but it also says replace dbname with database name... I never remember I set up a db name, where do I find it? This is the connection string I have:

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.pfose.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: You can use the _default_ database name `test`. Once, you connect, you can see what other databases are there.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

*By default, the **<dbname>** is test* but to create your own dbname, you need to change the **<dbname>** to the name of database you're interested to use. MongoDB Atlas will automatically create the db for you based on the name.
For example: `Creating a db for Qlabs with username=Que and password=pin123`

```js
mongodb+srv://Que:pin123@cluster0.pfose.mongodb.net/Qlabs?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score 18):

For those who wanna create db in with GUI

[image]

Comment: Yes, after loading example data, then under Collections tab I can see "Create Database" as you showed above.

Answer (score 6):

If you have made an atlas account and went through the tutorial then they may have made you make a mock cluster, by default it's name will be **Cluster0**. That's what your  will be.

Answer (score 4):

**

> By default the db name is <**test**> if you don't put anything in connection
> string also it will create a db, named as **test**.

**

But if you want to use your own specific db name, there is multiple method, I am specifing two only

**Method 1:** Speicy the db name directly in your connection string it will create a db for you

*Ex of connection string:* `'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster_name>.jqzujwt.mongodb.net/<dbname(optional)>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'`

**Method 2:** From mongodb web UI (https://account.mongodb.com/account/login) you can create also

*I am attaching the screenshoots for the better reference*

> After login using your credential it will land you on the below page

[image: landing view of mongo web after login]

> Click on the **browse collections** buttom
>
> It will redirct to below page

[image: browse collection screen when there is no collection]

> from here you have to click on **add my own data** buttom
>
> then the below popup will come you have to enter the D**atabase name**
> and **Collection name** and finally click on **create butom**

[image: create db and collection popup]

Final screenshoot after createing the db and collection

[image: screenshoot after createing the db and collection]

now if you want tocreate more db just click on **+ Create Database** buttom and repeat the above step... booom...

Answer (score 1):

Who have try the precedent answers and it won't work like me, you just have to include the --password  field with the URL you have to past it in your shell,without missing to change the dbname to the default dbname 'test' exmple:
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.otnlg.mongodb.net/test" --username mourad54 --password txt147

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Click on Cluster0 (Cluster name)

[image]

It will bring you to the Cluster Overview page

Step 2: Click on Collections

[image]

It will show a list of databases. you can read name and create/delete databases from here.

Now lets interact with one of the database `sample_mflix` > collection `movies`

[image]

here is the sample code to Query/Search for a movie that has the title 'Back to the Future' from `movies collection`:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// Replace the uri string with your MongoDB deployment's connection string.
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@<cluster-url>?retryWrites=true&writeConcern=majority";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();

    const database = client.db('sample_mflix');
    const movies = database.collection('movies');

    // Query for a movie that has the title 'Back to the Future'
    const query = { title: 'Back to the Future' };
    const movie = await movies.findOne(query);

    console.log(movie);
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

ref: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/