# How do I get NextAuth's MongoDB Adaptor to use a specific database name when using database?

Tags: database, mongodb, next.js, next-auth

I'm following [this short guide](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/mongodb) on how to use the MongoDB Adaptor with [NextAuth.js](https://next-auth.js.org/). It sort of works. After I install it like so:

```
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/mongodb"

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  ...
}
```

I am able to see user data in MongoDB Atlas! Hurray!

[image]

[image]

But as you can see, the name of the database is called "test". :(

Instead, I would like it to use the database I have configured for it. (That database also has the rest of my application's data.)

My .env.local

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27117
DB_NAME=my-app-db
```

My question is, how do I get the MongoDB Adaptor of NextAuth.js to use a specific database name?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63224330/where-do-i-find-my-dbname-for-mongodb-connection-string

Comment: Yes, I guess i need a way to name my database, but my uri doesn't have a name in it. My ur is localhost, so it doesn't have much. I guess it's fine the name being test while in dev anyway....