# Unable to send blob payload in FormData

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-data

I'm playing around with the `FormData` API. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tLqch5x2/2/) is the fiddle I'm using - I'm trying to inject blobs into my form and submit via AJAX.

```
//ic0 and tc0 are canvases
//image0 and thumb0 are file inputs
function ajaxSubmit(){
    var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
    ic0.toBlob(
        function(blob){
            fd.set("image0", blob, "image0.jpg");
        }, "image/jpeg", 0.7);
    tc0.toBlob(
        function(blob){
            fd.set("thumb0", blob, "thumb0.jpg");
        }, "image/jpeg", 0.7);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/ajax-upload/", true);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Browser behaviour is a little ... odd:

## Chrome 50 (in Ubuntu)

Not able to do it, gives:

```
Failed blob:https%3A//fiddle.jshell.net/uuid4 to load resource: the server responded with 404
```

But I thought `FormData.set()` was supported now? It seems to work with non-blobs?

## Firefox 46 (in Ubuntu)

Doesn't seem work if `FormData()` object is not initialized with a  DOM object that already has the necessary file inputs (appended normal inputs are posted however). `FormData.set()` does not seem to work with file inputs and blobs (you'll note that `thumb0` is null in the payload despite calling `fd.set("thumb0", blob, "thumb0.jpg")` on it. You can verify that it's set by doing `console.log(fd.get("thumb0"))` just after setting. You'll also note that the payload of `image0` is incorrectly your original image, not the resized canvas image.

---

It's inconvenient not being able to customise your multipart `FormData` with javascript. I'm a javascript noob - am I just doing something completely wrong here, or are these browsers not correctly supporting the `FormData` API? How can I submit `image0` and `thumb0` correctly in my fiddle?

---

Edit: OK, going to bounty this. I know there are big jquery-dependent libraries like blueimp out there, and I think they base64 the data rather than transmitting as a file input (plus I want to avoid jquery). I only have to support the latest Chrome or Firefox for this project and I'm really hoping I can keep the code as clean as the `FormData` API seems to suggest I might be able to. Can anyone successfully grab an image off a canvas and insert it into the POST payload as a file? I'd like to be able to access it in `request.FILES` in django.

Comment: I might be wrong but shouldn't you send the files object to the server instead of the blob? fd.set('image',e.target.files[0]') for single file? Also make sure that the form is multipart

Comment: Looking at the request's `Request Headers` and the `Request Payload`, the images seem to be sent just fine. And the server seems to return a `404` and not `400` or something.

Comment: Shouldn't you make sure that it posts to your actual server first? Right now it posts to a domain of jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think one thing you are missing here is the asynchronous nature of javascript. In your `ajaxSubmit` method -

```
function ajaxSubmit(){
    var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
    ic0.toBlob(function(blob){
        fd.set("image0", blob, "image0.jpg");
    }, "image/jpeg", 0.7);                // this call is asynchronous
    tc0.toBlob(function(blob){
        fd.set("thumb0", blob, "thumb0.jpg");
    }, "image/jpeg", 0.7);                // this call is also asynchronous
    /*
       hence the below code may get executed before
          fd.set("image0", blob, "image0.jpg");
       this statement. which it does. 
       that is why the canvas files are not submitted.  
    */
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/ajax-upload/", true);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Try synchronising the code like this

```
function ajaxSubmit(){
   var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
   ic0.toBlob(function(blob){
      fd.set("image0", blob, "image0.jpg");
      tc0.toBlob(function(blob){
         fd.set("thumb0", blob, "thumb0.jpg");
         console.log(blob);
         console.log("Just blobbed thumb0");

         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open("POST", "fileuploadbackend.jsp", true);
         //xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
         xhr.send(fd);
      }, "image/jpeg", 0.7);

   }, "image/jpeg", 0.7);
}
```

also as **jornare** has suggested you should comment out the line

```
URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
```

which is causing error in chrome. Invoke it after the loading image is done.

also you have multiple elements with same id,

```
<input id="image0" name="image0" type="file" />
<label for="image0">image0</label> 
<input id="image0" name="thumb0" type="file" />
```

this isn't creating problem in your code but the id's should be different.

**UPDATE**

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLqch5x2/5/).

Note: change the request url to your corresponding url.

Follow these links to get more insight on asynchronous behaviour of javascript and how AJAX request callbacks are handled.

- [How does Asynchronous Javascript Execution happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104474/how-does-asynchronous-javascript-execution-happen-and-when-not-to-use-return-st)
- [Developer Mozilla - Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)
- [How does javascript handle AJAX request in background.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575589/how-does-javascript-handle-ajax-responses-in-the-background/7575649#7575649)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Can you recommend a link where I can read up on the asynchronous execution of functions?

Comment: @Escher are you facing any other problem?

Comment: No, sorry for the delay; bounties can't be awarded within 24hrs of offering them. I tried yesterday but it wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through your fiddle, you were cleaning up the dataURL before it was loaded, and therefore the thumbnails did not load at all. (The 404)

I made an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tLqch5x2/3/

```
function handleFiles(e){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        var width = 30;
        var height = img.height * 30/img.width;
        e.target.ic0.width = width ;
        e.target.ic0.height = height ;
        e.target.tc0.width = width/2 ;
        e.target.tc0.height = height/2;
        var ctx = e.target.ic0.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        ctx = e.target.tc0.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width/2, height/2);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src); //clean up memory here instead
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    //clean up to prevent memory leak
    //URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src); //too soon
}
```

It still has a 404, but now from trying to post to a url that does not exist on jsfiddle.net. Please give it a try in your environment.

Note that there are also some other minor changes in both the html and the code. (improper naming the images, and no need to reference the existing form when creating the new form for submission)

Comment: Thanks, obviously I know very little about memory management in javascript. The 404 is OK, I just wanted to inspect the request payload. In this case I didn't need to reference the existing form when creating a new one for submission, but the project I am working on has about 20 more fields that are populated from the form, hence why I use it to instantiate new `FormData`.