# Javascript (Node) Pushing Object onto Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm playing with Node and have a strange problem (well, strange to me).  It's been a long time since I did any Javascript, so the problem is likely staring me in the face.

I'm iterating through a list of JSON text files in a directory, parsing the text from each file.  It moves through the directory correctly; when I check with console.log, each object appears correct.

However, when I attempt to push this onto an array, nothing happens, the size remains one at the end of the loop.  It feels like a scope issue.

Thanks for any advice.

```
app.get("/people/:value1/metrics/:value2", function(req, res) {
   var value1 = req.params.value1;
   var value2 = req.params.value2;
   var personPath = "people/" + value1 + "/" + value2;
   var content;
   var data = [];

   fs.readdir( personPath, function(err, files) {
     if(err) {
        console.log(err);
     }
     files.forEach( function (file, index ) {
       content = fs.readFileSync(personPath + '/' + file);
       console.log(JSON.parse(content));  //Correctly outputs the object.
       content = JSON.parse(content);
       data.push(content);
     });
   });
   console.log(data.length);  //Always 0.
   res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: This looks like asynchronous code, move your send into the readdir

Comment: Thanks for the advice all, that's great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.readdir` is an asynchronous execution. Your `console.log(data.length)` is executing before the `fs.readdir` execution has completed.

This also means your `res.send` is executing prematurely as well.

**Executing Synchronously**

Consider using `fs.readdirSync` if you'd like to keep the order of operations in your code the same:

```
app.get("/people/:value1/metrics/:value2", function(req, res) {
   var value1 = req.params.value1;
   var value2 = req.params.value2;
   var personPath = "people/" + value1 + "/" + value2;
   var content;
   var data = [];

   fs.readdirSync( personPath ).forEach(function(file, index) {
       content = fs.readFileSync(personPath + '/' + file);
       console.log(JSON.parse(content));  //Correctly outputs the object.
       content = JSON.parse(content);
       data.push(content); //I'm sure this is push references that are destroyed when out of scope.
   });
   console.log(data.length);  //Always 0.
   res.send(data);
});
```

More on fs.readdirSync here:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options

**Executing Asynchronously**

You should take this time to learn more about asynchronous execution. This post has a great explanation: [How does Asynchronous Javascript Execution happen? and when not to use return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104474/how-does-asynchronous-javascript-execution-happen-and-when-not-to-use-return-st)

If you move your `console.log` and `res.send` within the scope of the `fs.readdir`, this should solve your problem:

```
app.get("/people/:value1/metrics/:value2", function(req, res) {
   var value1 = req.params.value1;
   var value2 = req.params.value2;
   var personPath = "people/" + value1 + "/" + value2;
   var content;
   var data = [];

   fs.readdir( personPath, function(err, files) {
     if(err) {
        console.log(err);
     }
     files.forEach( function (file, index ) {
       content = fs.readFileSync(personPath + '/' + file);
       console.log(JSON.parse(content));
       content = JSON.parse(content);
       data.push(content);
     });
     console.log(data.length);  //placed within the scope of fs.readdir
     res.send(data);
   });
});
```

EDIT: One other thing to note is that `.forEach` is not asynchronous. Syntactically, both `fs.readdir` and `.forEach` are similar but `.forEach` is a blocking method. This means that every iteration will complete before the next line executes. So moving your `console.log` and `res.send` right *after* the `.forEach` should yield the desired results.

More on `.forEach` being a blocking method here: [JavaScript, Node.js: is Array.forEach asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous)

Answer (score 1):

As it is asynchronous function code like this:

```
 files.forEach( function (file, index ) {
       content = fs.readFileSync(personPath + '/' + file);
       console.log(JSON.parse(content));  //Correctly outputs the object.
       content = JSON.parse(content);
       callback(content);     
   });

callback(content)
{
   data.push(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about async execution, and put this block:

```
console.log(data.length);
res.send(data);
```

right before the last bracket in `fs.readdir`