# Using lb-services count servcie in angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I am using below code in my angular using lbservices, I want to get value of count, but I instead of output as a1=8 and a2=8, I am getting result as  a1=8 and a2=2,

```
var getOrganisationCount = function () {
                var count = 2;
                var query = {};
                Organisation
                    .count()
                    .$promise
                    .then(function (response) {
                        count = response.count;
                        console.log('a1===' + count);
                    });
                console.log('a2=' + count);
            };
            getOrganisationCount();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getOrganisationCount` function is making a network call to Organisation model that you have in your application.This network call `Organisation.count().$promise` is an async call and the code inside `then` block will be executed once you get a response from the server, ie: when the async operation is finished.

But the code `console.log('a2=' + count)` is not inside `then` block and it will be executed before the response comes from your server. Since the value of `count` is 2 initially, you get the output as 2 while the second
console statement runs after the response, its value gets updated and you get the output as 8.

If you run your code you will see that `console.log('a2=' + count)` is ouput first then `console.log('a1===' + count)` which is a proof to what I explained above.

If you want to understand more about how asynchronous function works, you can go through this well described [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17439761/2188949).

Answer (score 0):

Because a1 value is printed once the response from the async call is recieved, whereas a2 is printed immediately.

Code inside `then` callback is called when the server response has been recieved, whereas other code executes sequentially.

**Update:** Since you are working with promise, you should return promise from the function call, which the caller can then resolve.

```
var getOrganisationCount = function() {
  var count = 2;
  var query = {};
  return Organisation
    .count()
    .$promise
    .then(function(response) {
      count = response.count;
      console.log('a1===' + count);
      return count;
    });
};
getOrganisationCount().then(function(count) {
  console.log('a2=' + count);
});
```

Make note how the function now returns a promise instead of `count`

Comment: Can you tell me the solution for this problem