# JavaScript assigning value to variable from callback function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign a value to variable from a callback, but in *console.log* it shows me **undefined**.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var threadsList = threads(data => {
  return data
})

console.log(threadsList)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Asynchronous Javascript Execution happen? and when not to use return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104474/how-does-asynchronous-javascript-execution-happen-and-when-not-to-use-return-st)

Comment: it might no data is returned!

Comment: It would help to see the definition of `threads()`

Comment: Your arrow function is returning data to `threads()` If `threads()` is not returning that data back, it will not be going into `threadsList` As an illustration try `var threadsList = threads(data => {
  console.log(data);
})` This should log your data showing you that the callback was called.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
threads(data => {
  this.$data.threads = data
})
```