# Why does Javascript callback fire after FOR loop runs, when it is in the for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, callback, geocode

I have a Google Distance Matrix working, but need to account for more than 25 destinations, so I'm breaking my array into slices to send 25 destinations at a time. It works, sort of, but the thing I don't understand is the ORDER of how FOR, Functions, and Callbacks work. The callback logs all happen after the FOR loop completes, but they actually have the right data in them, I don't understand why.

This leaves me unable to check for the completion of the FOR loop, because the callbacks won't have happened, so I can't get to the array that is being built from the object that Google kicks back as a response.

Assume that xx starts at 0, and the destination[] is working list of lat/longs.

These are output in console (not variables):

```
calculate =  1
calculate =  2
calculate =  3
calculate =  4
after for =  4
callback =  4
callback =  4
callback =  4
callback =  4
```

This is the chunk of code in question:

```
        var ii,jj,tempServArr,maxZips = 25;
            for (ii=0,jj=destinations.length; ii<jj; ii+=maxZips) {
                tempServArr = destinations.slice(ii,ii+maxZips);
                xx++;
                calculateDistances(zip_latlng, tempServArr);
            }
            console.log("after for = ",xx);
        });
    });
}

function calculateDistances(origin, destinations) {
    console.log("calculate = ",xx);
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [origin],
            destinations: destinations,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
        console.log("callback = ",xx);
        var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
        for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Asynchronous Javascript Execution happen? and when not to use return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104474/how-does-asynchronous-javascript-execution-happen-and-when-not-to-use-return-st)

Comment: You're dealing with asynchronous calls. The callback does not fire until it receives a response from the server which can be

Comment: @Shadowfool which can be....?

Comment: @James Is this as simple as the response just takes longer to return then the for loop runs? In which case, is there a way to check for the final response from the last callback that is run?

Comment: sure.  Set a global counter to zero.  In each callback, increment that counter then test if it equals the number of items in the array, if so, execute some final function.

Comment: Thanks @James, that's what I've ended up trying to do. The asynch code threw me. Thanks for the link! (learning as I go).