# Node js return not returning anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to recover the value of a function but it doesn't returns anything

This is the function (Request is an async function that makes a get petition):

```
var getVolumesOKCoin = function(pair){
  request('https://www.okcoin.com/api/v1/depth.do?symbol=' + pair, function (error, response, body) {
    return body;
  });
}
```

And this is how I recover the value

```
var  retObj = getVolumesOKCoin(pair);
```

The value of  retObj is undefined.

What is the best way to recover the value?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry about the names of the functions, they are the same in my code, I edited to simplify the question

Comment: You can [edit] your question to fix that.

Comment: @FelixKling edited thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: your function is called `getVolumesOKCoin` and not `getVolumes`.

But still your function won't return anything, because you are calling an async function that needs some time to receive data before returning it. [See this question here about how asynchronous calls work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104474/how-does-asynchronous-javascript-execution-happen-and-when-not-to-use-return-st).

One solution would be to wrap your function body inside a so called `Promise` and resolve it as soon as data was received.

```
var getVolumesOKCoin = function(pair) {
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
    request('https://www.okcoin.com/api/v1/depth.do?symbol=' + pair, (error, response, body) => {
      resolve( body );
    } );
  } );
}

getVolumesOKCoin()
  .then( ( body ) => {
    console.log( body );
  } )
  .catch( ( err ) => {
    console.error( 'Error!' );
  } );
```

Also make sure, `request` is defined.

Comment: *"that's why you get undefined."* No, that's not the case. If the name was really incorrect, then they would get a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @lumio Works perfectly, and the comment about the undefined was done after your solution my bad not yours

Answer (score 0):

Simple add return to the request.

```
var getVolumesOKCoin = function(pair){
  return request('https://www.okcoin.com/api/v1/depth.do?symbol=' + pair, function (error, response, body) {
    return body;
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? What does `request` return?