# Empty Array of google.maps.LatLng Objects

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

First of all, I'm trying to create Heatmaps using `google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer`.

I'm trying to call the function `codeAddress` n times, and every time I call It, It's supposed to create a new `google.maps.LatLng` object in the global array `locationsList` , but when I try to return `locationsList` on the function `getPoints` it is empty.
Any idea why?

```
var locationsList = [];
var counter = 0;

    function getPoints(latitude, longitude) {   
            codeAddress(" APIAI, SP, Brasil",2271.96);
            codeAddress(" Avaré, SP, Brasil",8.77);
            codeAddress(" Barueri, SP, Brasil",263.1);
            codeAddress(" Caçapava, SP, Brasil",2130.24);
            codeAddress(" Cajati, SP, Brasil",157.26);
            codeAddress(" Campinas, SP, Brasil",83.28);
            codeAddress(" CARAGUATATUBA, SP, Brasil",325.08);

        console.log("All codeaddress ended "+locationsList.length); // prints 0 (array disappears?)

          return locationsList;
        }

function codeAddress(endereco, peso) {   
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': endereco}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {                     
    var thislat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var thislong = results[0].geometry.location.lng();


        locationsList[this.contador] = {location: new google.maps.LatLng(thislat,thislong), weight: peso};
        console.log(locationsList.length);
        contador++;

                 } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests), geocoding requests are asynchronous:

> Accessing the Geocoding service is asynchronous, since the Google Maps API needs to make a call to an external server. For that reason, you need to pass a callback method to execute upon completion of the request.

You can read more about how asynchronous code works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104474/how-does-asynchronous-javascript-execution-happen-and-when-not-to-use-return-st).

Regarding this code:

```
function getPoints(latitude, longitude) {   
  codeAddress(" APIAI, SP, Brasil",2271.96);
  codeAddress(" Avaré, SP, Brasil",8.77);
  codeAddress(" Barueri, SP, Brasil",263.1);
  codeAddress(" Caçapava, SP, Brasil",2130.24);
  codeAddress(" Cajati, SP, Brasil",157.26);
  codeAddress(" Campinas, SP, Brasil",83.28);
  codeAddress(" CARAGUATATUBA, SP, Brasil",325.08);

  console.log("All codeaddress ended "+locationsList.length); // prints 0 (array disappears?)

  return this.locationsList;
}
```

JavaScript does not wait for each geocode request to finish before executing the next call to `codeAddress`. So all the code in the `getPoints` function is executed immediately so by the time the code reaches `return this.locationsList`, the geocoding requests are still happening in the background and the `locationsList` array is still empty.

#### Update

Additionally, as @Preston mentioned in his comment:

> The Geocoding Service in the Javascript API has a [client-side rate limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#usage-limits-for-google-maps-javascript-api-services) that prevents too many requests being sent simultaneously. With too many undelayed sequential codeAddress() calls, you may run into OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors. You may want to put some delay logic in your code if you encounter this.

Comment: Also, to add to this answer, the Geocoding Service in the Javascript API has a [client-side rate limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#usage-limits-for-google-maps-javascript-api-services) that prevents too many requests being sent simultaneously. With too many undelayed sequential `codeAddress()` calls, you may run into `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`errors. You may want to put some delay logic in your code if you encounter this.

Comment: Thanks @Preston! I added it to my answer. 