# Javascript disabling .onClick event

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("image1").onclick = function() {
    imageClickedOn()
}
```

all I want is so that when I click the image, I can't click it again until the function is over.

Comment: what sort of element is image1 ? a button ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What do you mean by “function is over”? Do not use `.onclick`; instead use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). It has a `once` setting if that’s what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can used a variable to determine if `imageClickedOn()` should be allowed to run. You would set it to true when the function starts and false when the function ends.

```
var isImageClicked = false;

document.getElementById("image1").onclick = function() {
    if (!isImageClicked) {
       imageClickedOn()
    }

}
imageClickedOn() {
    isImageClicked = true;
    ...
    isImageClicked = false;
}
```

Comment: i did exactly this, and it just skips over the if statement like it wasn't there so that doesn't work.

Comment: @Juan184 Then you’re not giving us sufficient details as to what `imageClickedOn` does. `isImageClicked = false` is supposed to be executed when that function is “over”, whatever that means. If you have asynchronous calls or timeouts, you need to put that line _inside_ them. If that’s the case, please familiarize yourself with [asynchronous execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7104474/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like with a timeout?

```js
let canClick = true;
img.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (canClick) {
    //your function goes here
    console.log("image clicked");
  
    canClick = false;
    setTimeout(() => canClick = true, 2000); // 2000 milliseconds === 2 seconds
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png">
```

This will create a delay of 2 seconds before the user can click the image again.

Answer (score 0):

When clicked, you can add a CSS class with `pointer-events` set to `none` to prevent subsequent clicks. Once your function has completed, you can remove the class.

```js
function imageClickedOn() {
  // returns a promise that resolves in 1s
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000))
}

document.getElementById("image1").addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
  console.log("Image clicked")
  const img = e.target

  // Add class
  img.classList.add("disable-click")
  
  // Wait for function to complete
  await imageClickedOn()
  
  // Remove class
  img.classList.remove("disable-click")
})
```

```css
.disable-click {
  pointer-events: none;
  
  /* the below just lets you see when it is not clickable */
  filter: blur(5px);
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<img id="image1" width="100" height="100" src="https://picsum.photos/100">
```

---

If your element is an `<a>` or `<button>`, you're probably better off toggling the `disabled` property instead.

Answer (score -2):

You can follow.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_dom;

But it not work you can try

$("#image1").click(()=>{
"function "
})