# Is javascript Sychronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, synchronous

I have confused with synchronous and assynchronous in javascript is javascript is a synchronous or assynchronous ,suggest your idea or any relevant website , thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking for it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous

Comment: It's both synchronous and asynchronous, take a look at [Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

Answer (score 1):

You can write either synchronous or asynchronous code in `JavaScript`. It is not only one or another. For instance, an `ajax` call is asynchronous by it's nature. On the other hand, when you execute a function to show an alert with a message when a button will be clicked is clearly an not asynchronous job. Hence, as you understand there are areas in `JavaScript` as in other programming languages, where we make use of asynchronous programming and others in which we make use of synchronous programming.