# which functions in javascript (in browser) can run in async mode?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

As I know, JavaScript is single-threaded.  Only a few functions can run in async mode such as setTimeout, setInterval, XHR, ... etc.  Also all the event callback will be run in async mode. Is there any other JavaScript function can run in async mode?

Comment: In which version of Javascript, and on what browser / in what engine?

Comment: I want to ask a question that which functions in javascript will be ran in async mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the HTML5 [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) API, which allows you to a run parallel threads in JavaScript.

Comment: There is also File API's  FileReader  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader and all event listeners can bee seen as async.

Comment: @Deni: You changed my title and body of my question which is not what I want to ask.  I changed a little bit.  Hope you can understand.

Comment: as I know, setTimeout and setInterval will let my callback function run into a async manner.  I just want to know is any others way to run callback function in async way.

Comment: JavaScript is async and single threaded, additionally there is a HTML5 api which allows you to use multiple threads. Every event that occurs on a web page is async. Can you share more details about your use case ?

Comment: I think this post answered part of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous

Quote: "Javascript is always synchronous and single-threaded"

Comment: yep, that's true, additionally if you want true multi thread environment for background calculations you can use the web worker api