# Weird AJAX behaviour with loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a pair of nested AJAX request that do not behave correctly.
The first gets a list of `albums`, and the second one gets executed for every album, giving me a list of `tracks`.

```
$.ajax({
    url:getPHPSite(),
    method:"POST",  
    data:{
        query: "SELECT id_album FROM albums;"
    },
    success: function(response){
      var albums=JSON.parse(response);
      for(var i=0; i<albums.length;i++){
          var albumID=albums[i]['id_album'];
             getTracks(function(courses) {
              //do something
            }
            }, albumID);


        }  
    }, ....//error handler and everything else
```

The `getTracks()` function actually performs the second AJAX request and returns an **array of tracks** with a `callback`

```
function getTracks(callback, albumID){
    $.ajax({
        url:getPHPSite(),
        method:"POST",   
        data:{
            query: "SELECT idtracks FROM tracksWHERE id_album=" + albumID + ";"
        },


        success: function(response){
            array_tracks=JSON.parse(response);   
            callback(array_tracks);
        }, //...everything else
```

By putting breakpoints, I discovered that the first `for loop` is executed **separately**

```
albumID=1
albumID=2
albumID=3
...end
```

and only then the `getTracks()` is executed.

I want the `getTracks()` to be executed for every iteration of albums.

Why does it happen and how can I resolve this?

Comment: That's because JavaScript is synchronous. Read the answer for it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous 

Basically, you are creating the AJAX calls, but the loop continues afterwards before the AJAX resolves.

Comment: you should **never** send a mysql query wholesale via ajax!! i hope this is just a demo site because you're just inviting trouble if you execute the query without any form of input sanitation at all!!

Comment: yes this is a demo, don't worry. Thanks for the link @Hoyen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have problems with the Javascript asynchronous way, you could disable with the `async: false` flag http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings, but you will loose the javascript power.

One of the ways I think this could be done is create an array with all the resultant Ids of the first endpoint, and then do the foreach to that array, instead of embedding ajax inside ajax, but just for code maintainability.

Comment: Ok, I didn't want to use `async:false` because it's **deprecated**, so I managed the ajax calls using the `.done()`(the second call is execeuted inside `.done()`).
About your solution, I found it really good, and implemented it into another section of the program, which isn't important anyway. So thank you very much :-)

Comment: Awesome @RiccardoLomazzi :D