# How to put a getJSON() number to an array?

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I have a getJSON request. This request is working fine, but i can't store the output data in array.

Here is the current code:

```
var loc = [];

jQuery.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Los Angeles, CA 90012&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
            var latlng = (p.lat, p.lng);

            loc.push(latlng);                   
 });

console.log('Final: '+loc);
```

The console is showing this: 'Final: ', so the `loc.push(latlng)` isn't working.

How can I store getJSON datas in the outside array?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9fd1q8bp/)

Comment: put console.log('Final: '+loc); just after loc.push(latlng);

Comment: @ParthPatel I want the result outside the getJSON.

Comment: loc is globally initialized so you can use any where but what you are doing is that you are printing console.log('Final: '+loc); before you get response from getJSON(). so you can not find any result on your console. Javascript is asynchronous when AJAX. Please refer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous