# Deferring form captcha reset until after submit() has executed

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm using Google's reCAPTCHA on a form and after every submit I need it reset, because if the server-side validation fails and the user resubmits the same form, the captcha will be invalid. I'm using plain javascript, *not* using ajax/jquery, the form opens a new page (instead of reloading the current one). Here's my code:

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.submit();
    setTimeout(function(){ grecaptcha.reset(myCaptcha); }, 0);
}
```

I'm using `setTimeout` to put the reset code in the event loop queue.

**My question is, will this work every time? Is `submit()` synchronous, i.e. it will always execute before whatever is in the event loop queue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035662/2483271):

> JavaScript is always synchronous and single-threaded. If you're executing a JavaScript block of code on a page then no other JavaScript on that page will currently be executed.

So this.submit() will run to completion before setTime() begins executing.