# React setState not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

So I have this:

```js
let total = newDealersDeckTotal.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
},
0);

console.log(total, 'tittal'); //outputs correct total
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({ dealersOverallTotal: total });
}, 10);

console.log(this.state.dealersOverallTotal, 'dealersOverallTotal1'); //outputs incorrect total
```

`newDealersDeckTotal` is just an array of numbers `[1, 5, 9]` e.g.
however `this.state.dealersOverallTotal` does not give the correct total but `total` does? I even put in a timeout delay to see if this solved the problem.
any obvious or should I post more code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36087156/4453045

Comment: Besides what is said in the answers, you are explicitly logging the value of the state, *before* you are calling `setState`.

Comment: @FelixKling no I'm calling this.state _after_ I set it. I am logging a variable before. no?

Comment: Because of the timeout your `setState` is indeed executed after you log the state. I think what you meant to do in debugging was putting the `console.log` part inside the timeout, and the `setState` outside.

Comment: @FabianSchultz can you explain one thing I'm not getting then. consider this code: `if(this.state.playersOverallTotal > 21){
      console.log('bust');
      this.setState({playerBusted: true});
    }`
when it gets to over 21, the log fires but the state does not change and then only changes once the number increments again.
e.g. if it got to 24 it would not set the state but then if it got to 28 for example it would

Comment: Can't reproduce it, maybe ask as a seperate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 319, accepted):

`setState()` is usually asynchronous, which means that at the time you `console.log` the state, it's not updated yet. Try putting the log in the callback of the `setState()` method. It is executed after the state change is complete:

```
this.setState({ dealersOverallTotal: total }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.dealersOverallTotal, 'dealersOverallTotal1');
});
```

Comment: In addition to that, the OP explicitly logs the state value *before* they call `setState`.

Comment: This works for me as well, in the past I have used this: `this.setState({someVar: newValue},function(){ console.log("force update}); ' but for some reason it was't worring any more, when I updated the code as describe above it work.   any idea why?

Comment: @Jozcar Should work also, syntax wasn't right (missing parentheses): `this.setState({someVar: newValue},function(){ console.log("force update") });`

Comment: https://imgur.com/Ku0OjTl Please tell me what should i do to get rid of this problem.

Comment: This does not work if you use `useState` hook in a functional component. Use `useEffect` instead for an effect after rendering.

Comment: I had completely forgot the fact that it's async call and did all possible code changes except for this one and here you saved my brain from burning out. thanks

Comment: I never see the output, in addition the key which I was trying to update becomes undefined.

Comment: How do I do the same thing with a state management library such as zustand?

Answer (score 51):

In case of hooks, you should use `useEffect` hook.

```
const [fruit, setFruit] = useState('');

setFruit('Apple');

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Fruit', fruit);
}, [fruit])
```

Comment: Great, it works with useEffect. But why does it need one?

Comment: `useEffect` runs on every re-render, and if the items passed into the array are state variable sand changed. So when the fruit changed and component re-renders, that useEffect will run.

Comment: I run setFruit and console.log fruit outside of useEffect, and it does not change. :/

Answer (score 29):

setState is asynchronous. You can use callback method to get updated state.

```
changeHandler(event) {
    this.setState({ yourName: event.target.value }, () => 
    console.log(this.state.yourName));
 }
```

Answer (score 19):

I had an issue when setting react state multiple times (it always used default state). Following this [react/github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16858) issue worked for me

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  foo: "abc",
  bar: 123
});

// Do this!
setState(prevState => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    foo: "def"
  };
});
setState(prevState => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    bar: 456
  };
});
```

Comment: setting the state like this fixed it for me

Comment: This fixed an issue that none of the other suggestions were fixing.

Answer (score 17):

The setState is asynchronous in react, so to see the updated state in console use the callback as shown below (Callback function will execute after the setState update)

```
this.setState({ email: 'test@example.com' }, () => {
   console.log(this.state.email)
)}
```

Comment: THANK YOU this is it, you have to directly set the variable

Answer (score 16):

The `setState()` operation is *asynchronous* and hence your `console.log()` will be executed before the `setState()` mutates the values and hence you see the result.

To solve it, log the value in the callback function of `setState()`, like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({dealersOverallTotal: total},
    function(){
       console.log(this.state.dealersOverallTotal, 'dealersOverallTotal1');
    });
}, 10)
```

Comment: JavaScript is always synchronous.

Comment: @santoshsingh you have a misconception. API calls, timeouts all happen asynchronously.

Comment: As you mentioned above that javascript is asynchronous --- it's not correct. Its mainly synchronous and for cases it's asynchronous.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous

Comment: @santoshsingh. Ohh that was a mistake on my part. Didn't form the sentence correctly

Comment: very clever use of the callback to ensure the state is updated before the subsequent call!

Answer (score 14):

Using async/await

```
async changeHandler(event) {
    await this.setState({ yourName: event.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.yourName);
}
```

Comment: `setState` doesn't return a promise, so I don't expect this to work.

Answer (score 6):

As well as noting the asynchronous nature of setState, be aware that you may have competing event handlers, one doing the state change you want and the other immediately undoing it again. For example onClick on a component whose parent also handles the onClick. Check by adding trace. Prevent this by using e.stopPropagation.

Comment: Thanks for leaving this. Your comment pointed me in the right direction. I found the problematic code being updated in a conflicting event, then in that spot I used prevState callback to set new state as mentioned above by @Arun Gopalpuri
```
        this.setState(prevState=>{
            return {...prevState,
            newProperty
         }});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you work with funcions you need to use UseEffect to deal with setState's asynchrony (you can't use the callback as you did when working with classes). An example:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
 const [animal, setAnimal] = useState(null);

 function changeAnimal(newAnimal) {
  setAnimal(newAnimal);
  // here 'animal' is not what you would expect
  console.log("1", animal);
 }

 useEffect(() => {
  if (animal) {
   console.log("2", animal);
  }
 }, [animal]);

 return (
  <div className="App">
  <button onClick={() => changeAnimal("dog")} />
 </div>
 );
}
```

First console.log returns null, and the second one returns 'dog'

Answer (score 5):

I had the same situation with some convoluted code, and nothing from the existing suggestions worked for me.

My problem was that `setState` was happening from callback func, issued by one of the components. And my suspicious is that the call was occurring synchronously, which prevented `setState` from setting state at all.

Simply put I have something like this:

```
render() {
    <Control
        ref={_ => this.control = _}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onUpdated={this.handleUpdate} />
}

handleChange() {
    this.control.doUpdate();
}

handleUpdate() {
    this.setState({...});
}
```

The way I had to "fix" it was to put `doUpdate()` into `setTimeout` like this:

```
handleChange() {
    setTimeout(() => { this.control.doUpdate(); }, 10);
}
```

Not ideal, but otherwise it would be a significant refactoring.

Comment: This solved my issue, but I put the setState() inside of the setTimeout() instead.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot man. You just saved me from even more debugging.

Comment: wish there could be more of an elegant way to solve this, but this works, thanks

Answer (score 4):

just add `componentDidUpdate(){}` method in your code, and it will work.
you can check the life cycle of react native here:

https://images.app.goo.gl/BVRAi4ea2P4LchqJ8