# React, 2 setstate in same function: second one erase the first

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to run the code above but the state get updated only for idx. From what i understand the second function's setState will not get the updated state and thats why this happens. Is there a way to make it work properly (expect than merge the 2 functions in one)

```
doIt(idx,array) {
   this.doFirst(array);
   this.doSecond(idx);
}

doFirst(array){
   //bla bla bla code
   this.setState(test: {...this.state.test, array});
}

doSecond(idx) {
    // bla bla bla code
    this.setState(test: {...this.state.test, idx});
}
```

Comment: what is coming inside `array`?

Comment: `setState` can take a callback as it's second parameter. You could get fancy with that: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setState() is asynchronous.

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
>   update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
>   delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
>   does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

it takes an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. you can use that callback.

If the next state depends on the previous state, it is recommended to use the updater function form **setState(updater[, callback])**

```
doIt(idx,array) {
   this.doFirst(array, () => this.doSecond(idx));
}

doFirst(array, callback){
   //bla bla bla code
   this.setState(firstUpdaterFunction, callback);
}

doSecond(idx) {
    // bla bla bla code
    this.setState(2ndUpdaterFunction);
}
```

**References:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41446620/2073920

Answer (score 1):

Below two statement executed simultaneously.

```
this.doFirst(array);
this.doSecond(idx);
```

These both calling `setState`.`setState is asynchronous`. So, there is no guarantee that value will be updates sequentially. 
Beacause of this race call,the value is getting overwritten.
better to chain these call.

```
doIt(idx,array) {
   this.doFirst(array);   
}

doFirst(array){
   //bla bla bla code
   this.setState({test: {...this.state.test, array}},()=>{

    this.doSecond(idx); 
   });
}

doSecond(idx) { 
    this.setState({test: {...this.state.test, idx}});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly because your example setState calls aren't quite right, `this.setState(test: {...this.state.test, idx});`. Do you mean you're doing `this.setState({test: {...this.state.test, idx}});`? If so you should use a callback instead of an object like this:

`this.setState(() => ({ test: {...this.state.test, idx}})`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you just misplaced your brackets around your state object, so I added those.

At any rate, you want to use the updater function instead:

`this.setState((prevState, props) => ({test: {...prevState.test, array}});`

Note that this is probably not what you want as in ES 2015 it translates to:
`this.setState((prevState, props) => ({test: {...prevState.test, array: array}});`

You'd want to do the same thing for the other function as well. React batches set state calls together, so if you don't use the updater, there is a chance that you will be accessing a stale state for your successive function calls. That's probably what is happening in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, `setState` is asynchronous. If you need to use previous state I would like to point out that the first argument of [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is `updater`, it can take a function to calculate next state from the previous state:

```
doFirst(array){
   this.setState(previousState => ({ test: {...previousState.test, array} }));
}

doSecond(idx) {
    this.setState(previousState => ({ test: {...previousState.test, idx} }));
}
```