# setState doesn't work within an event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update state within an onClick event handler according to props.
in the console.log I'm getting empty string as the initial state value.

I already tried to change the component to function using state hooks instead of state.
I tried to use method to update the state when onClick is invoke.
I already tried to use the suggestions in the answers of a similar questions, this case is different, maybe because I'm using the setState within the event handler.

does any one know what is the problem here ?
thanks in advance!

```
class DropDownItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedItem : "" 
    }
    this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this)
  }

  updateItem (item) {
    this.setState({selectedItem : item})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => {
            this.updateItem(this.props.product)
            console.log("item",this.state.selectedItem)
          }}  
        >{this.props.product}</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem divider/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

here is the body of the parent component :

```
render() {




  const productItems = this.state.products.map((productValue,index) => {
    return(<DropDownItem key={index} product={productValue.name}  />)
  })

    return (
<div>

  {this.state.products[0] && Array.isArray(this.state.products)  ? 
     <div>
       <DropdownComponent
      isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} 
      toggle={this.toggle}
      product={productItems}

       />
     </div> :
     <div>loading...</div>}     
</div>

    )}
```

I want to update state in order to show the clicked dropdown item to the user.

Comment: `this.setState` is async, meaning when you log `this.state.selectedItem` it's still empty. Clicking it again should log the changed state.

Comment: What do you get if you console.log `this.props.product`? Can you show us how your component is being used (i.e. what props are you passing to it)?

Comment: setState is asynchronous. Try: this.setState({selectedItem: item}, ()=> { console.log("item", this.state.selectedItem) }); as described here https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Comment: thank you for the comments.
In the console log I'm getting this.props.product as the desired value.
I tried @camen6ert suggestion,Unfortunately I'm getting the same result.

Comment: I'm confused, why is your DropDownItem class (it appears to be a single dropdown item in a list) storing the information of whether or not it's selected inside its own state?  Shouldn't this be the container's job, passing an onClick bound to a particular list item down to the children?  Where are you consuming this.state.selectedItem other than the log statement?

Comment: yes you are right.
this was my first option, but I couldn't make it work so I tried to manage the state in my child component (DropDownItem)
for now I want to update the state and then I will show it to the user in my DropDownItem component.
does it make sense ? or should I do it in alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the updated state inside the callback provided as second argument in `setState`, like this

```
class DropDownItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedItem : "" 
    }
    this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this)
  }

  updateItem (item, callback) {
    this.setState({selectedItem : item}, callback)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => {
            this.updateItem(this.props.product, ()=>{
                console.log("item",this.state.selectedItem)
            })
          }}  
        >{this.props.product}</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem divider/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer.
It seems that is the solution but still the state doesn't change.

Comment: take a look at this fiddle and open the console before clicking https://jsfiddle.net/4p3wmko7/1/

Comment: Thank you!
Your answer helped me find the solution!

Answer (score 1):

`setState()` batches updates, so `this.state` will not immediately reflect the update.

The solution, as [@camen6ert already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976657/setstate-doesnt-work-within-an-event-handler#comment98604024_55976657), is to read `this.state` in `setState()`'s callback:

```js
class DropDown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {selectedItem: null}
  }
  updateItem(selectedItem, callback) {
    this.setState({selectedItem}, callback)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <select onChange={event => {
        this.updateItem(event.target.value,
          () => console.log('item', this.state.selectedItem))
      }}>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DropDown />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```