# React using method args in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm new to React and I'm trying to dynamically set the state of a card to "selected" or not. I have the click event working from child -> parent. However, when it gets into the parent I can't seem to get it to be assigned to state dynamically (because I may not know how many cards there are I obviously don't want to hard code this).

Here is my method:

```
handleCardClick(card) {
    let title = card.title;

    this.setState((preState, props) => ({
        title: true
    }));

    console.log('card: ', this.state);
}
```

I am aware that I'm not using the `preState` and `props` yet, but I will need them later.

How can I make the state hold the actual title and not the literal string "title"?

So instead of `{title: true}` it would be something like `{some_title: true}`

I am also getting a warning in VS Code the title is assigned but never used. I this not the best way to do this? Obviously, I don't want this warning every I do something like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Please see updated question

Comment: You can use bracket notation to set property from variable like this this.setState((preState, props) => ({
        [card.title]: true
    }));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to set property from variable like this

```
handleCardClick(card) {

    this.setState((preState, props) => ({
        [card.title]: true
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bracket notation to set dynamic key,

Also, use arrow functions in class properties to avoid binding `this.handleCardClick = this.handleCardClick.bind(this)`.

```js
handleCardClick = ({ title }) => {       // <-- No binding required.
    this.setState((preState, props) => ({
        [title]: true                    // Dynamic key
    }));
}
```

and in your `ParentCard`:

```js
cardAction = () => {
  if (this.state.myCard1 === true) {
     // ... do some action
  {
}
```