# ReactJS state change is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I have a button class called "DrawButton", that has this render

```
render() {
    return(
        <Button
            onClick={this.props.toggleDraw.bind(this)}
            style={{
                backgroundColor: this.props.drawMode ? 'red' : 'blue'
            }}
        >
            Draw
        </Button>
    );
}
```

And in parent App.js the state gets defined

```
state = {
        drawMode: false
}
```

and there is a handler function

```
toggleDraw = (e) => {
    console.log('App.js drawMode:' + this.state.drawMode);
    this.setState({
        drawMode: !this.state.drawMode
    });
    console.log('App.js drawMode:' + this.state.drawMode);
}
```

And finally the button:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <DrawButton 
            toggleDraw={this.toggleDraw} 
            drawMode={this.state.drawMode}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The state doesn't get updated properly.
It outputs the following:

First click on the Button

```
App.js drawMode:false
App.js:27
App.js drawMode:false
App.js:31
```

Before the setState ran, the drawMode is false after setState ran, the drawMode is still false.

But the button still gets a red background.

Second click on the Button:

```
App.js drawMode:true
App.js:22
App.js drawMode:true
App.js:26
```

But the button is blue again despise drawMode in state is set to true.

Why is this inconsistency happening?

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, so it won't be changed on next line of code when you log it

Comment: You've got your `.bind(this)` in the wrong place, it needs to be in the parent not the child.

Comment: How can I fix that it remains consistent?

Comment: You need to use `await` in the `async` function to get the right result.

Comment: @WisnuAdiNurcahyo What? there is no async function here.

Comment: @david That doesn't change the result

Comment: @bxyify Then you're not showing us all the code. With your code and my fix it works fine (bar the console log thing other people are talkign about) https://jsfiddle.net/dh7mkzwq/

Comment: @david Then you must have a different browser than me (Firefox) because your jsfiddle gives the exact same result when I click on the button (it gets red): App.js drawMode:false
show:27:5
App.js drawMode:false
show:31:5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `bind` was used incorrectly, in your `DrawButton` onClick handler, just call `this.props.toggleDraw`.
This code : `this.props.toggleDraw.bind(this)` should be in the constructor of `App.js` file.

Secondly, do not use the `console.log` to check the value of state after setting, because the `setState` function runs asynchronously, use `setState` callback to check the value after setting:

```
toggleDraw = (e) => {
    console.log('App.js drawMode:' + this.state.drawMode);
    this.setState(
        { drawMode: !this.state.drawMode },
        () => console.log('App.js drawMode:' + this.state.drawMode)
    ),
}
```

Comment: You are right, this fixes the console log problem. But now the state doesn't get passed correctly to all components. I just added another component and while button gets the updated state of drawMode, the other component defined before doesn't get it at the same time. I have to toggle it twice until it gets populated to the other component. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: could you add the code of "another" component, I will take a look on that.

Comment: Maybe I should create another question with that because that changes the question too much...