# useState hook always 1 step behind

Tags: reactjs

I have seen other questions with the exact same title, but none solved my problem:
This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Validation from './Validation/Validation';
import Char from './Char/Char';

function App() {
  const [textState, textSetState] = useState('');
  const [charsState, charsSetState] = useState([]);

  let inputChange = (event) => {
    textSetState(event.target.value);
    charsSetState(event.target.value.split('').map((char, index) => {
      return <Char char={char} key={index} click={() => { deleteCharHandler(index) }} />
    }));
  }

  const deleteCharHandler = (index) => {
    alert(textState);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" onChange={(event) => inputChange(event)} />
      <Validation text={textState} />
      {charsState}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the result:

[image]

When I click a character, it displays the value from 1 step behind, like the example above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Comment: React state is asynchronous the value of textState has not yet updated to the new value when you alert

Comment: Why are you storing components in state?

Comment: @BrianOgden Hello. No, because I need to delete a character when I click it, so adding a callback for when I change the state will not do the job.

Comment: is your goal to render text from input as sequence of `<Char>` and later delete some char after being clicked?

Comment: @skyboyer yes it is

Comment: @AsafAviv to re-render the components everytime I change the text

Comment: When you update the text the component is going to re-render, then just map over the text inside the JSX and render the `Char` components. when you want to remove a char just update the text state

Comment: One more thing: When I changed it to a class component, it worked as intended.

Comment: sure, because for class-based component you are accessing most recent `state` by reference `this.state`. While in functional components you are typically facing closure(and stale data in closure is reason you face this issue above)

Comment: @AsafAviv coreyward's answer + your comment solved it.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly acceptable question, not sure why thumbs down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting an array of rendered `Char` components in your state, then rendering it. There are a number of issues with this approach.

1. The local copy of the state (`charsState`) will not be updated immediately; instead React will re-render the component with the new value for state.
2. Since you are defining the `onClick` callback within the function, `deleteCharHandler` will always be referencing an outdated copy of the state.
3. Multiple state hooks being updated in lockstep in this way will cause additional re-renders to happen.

Since the naming in your example is a bit confusing it's hard to tell what the desired behavior is to make good recommendations for how to resolve or refactor.

Answer (score 2):

So there are a few things which may or may not be causing an issue so lets just clear a few things up:

1. You don't need to pass the anonymous function on the input:

   `<input type="text" onChange={inputChange} />` should suffice
2. As with OG state, it's never a good idea to call two setStates simultaneously, so lets combine the two:

   `const [state, setState] = useState({text: '', char: []});`

Once you've updated everything you should be setting one state object onClick.

3. Your Char object is using click instead of onClick? unless you are using that as a callback method i'd switch to:

   `return <Char char={char} key={index} OnClick={() => deleteCharHandler(index)} />`

If that doesn't fix your solution at the end, you can simply pass the `deleteCharHandler` the updated text value instead of re-grabbing the state value

Comment: 1. How will I access the value of the input?
2. I'll try it out
3. I use onClick on the component, I pass the function via prop.click

Comment: The onClick event will automatically pass through the event object as you aren't altering it.

Comment: No worries! Glad to help, although someone else just came in after with pretty much the same answer XD rip

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `useCallback` or to pass textState in parameter. the `deleteCharHandler` method doesn't change in time with the textState value.

try :

```
return <Char char={char} key={index} click={() => { deleteCharHandler(index, textState) }} />
...

const deleteCharHandler = (index, textState) => {
    alert(textState);
  }
```

or :

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
...
const deleteCharHandler = useCallback(
  (index) => {
    alert(textState);
  }, [textState]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function App() {
    const [textState, textSetState] = useState('');

    const inputChange = useCallback((event) => {
        textSetState(event.target.value);
    },[])

    function renderChars(){
        return textState.split('').map((char, index) => {
            return <Char char={char} key={index} click={() => { deleteCharHandler(index) }} />
        }));
    }

    const deleteCharHandler = useCallback( (index) => {
         alert(textState);
    }, [textState])

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="text" onChange={inputChange} />
            <Validation text={textState} />
           {renderChars()}
       </div>
   );
}
```