# useState with boolean value in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the code snippet below, when I click on Change button to change the value of `isLoading` ,
nothing happened (`isLoading` is false).

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

  const buttonHandler = () => {
    setIsLoading(current => !current)
    console.log(isLoading) // is false 
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={buttonHandler} type="button">
        Change
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried to change isLoading with the following ways but does not affect:

```
1-setIsLoading(current => !current)
2-setIsLoading(!isLoading)
3-setIsLoading(true)
```

Comment: State changes are asynchronous so you can't `console.log` them on the next line and see them changed. Try printg `isLoading` directly below your `useState` line, that way it will print when the componetn re-renders with the new state

Comment: This question is asked nearly daily. Please search SO before asking. Does this answer your question? [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Comment: State changes are asynchronous. So use component tab in developer tools to monitor the state changes.

Answer (score 23):

`setIsLoading` is an async function and you cannot get the state value immediately after update.

> **setState** actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains.  setState() does not immediately mutate this. Thus the setState calls are asynchronous as well as batched for better UI experience and performance. This applies on both `functional/Class` components.

**From React documentation**

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
>   Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>   You could read more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

If you want to get the updated state value then use `useEffect` hook with dependency array. React will execute this hook after each state update.

```js
const {useEffect, useState } = React;

const App = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const buttonHandler = () => {
    setIsLoading(current => !current)
  }

  useEffect( () => {
    console.log(isLoading);
}, [isLoading]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={buttonHandler} type="button">
        Change
      </button>

      {isLoading? "Loading...": null}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <div id="root">
      loading.....
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. You may want to use `useEffect` to access the latest value.

Here is a thread discussing the same issue: [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

State and hooks are asynchronous. You won't see a change in `isLoading` directly after calling `set...`, but only on the next render of the component, which will happen "soon enough".

If you do print the value of the statelet (as a string; `false` renders as nothing), you can see the change:

```
return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={buttonHandler} type="button">
        Change (now {"" + isLoading})
      </button>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
```

Don't use useState like this, you cannot get the state value immediately after update.

**Reference**: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

So, instead of this use: **useRef** (If you want to keep the object for the full lifetime of the component).

i.e.

```
const isLoading = useRef(false);
```

And later you can assign it as:

```
isLoading.current = true;
```

And you can use it as:

```
console.log(isLoading.current);
```

**Reference**: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Comment: Probably the original question was looking for an alternative to change a boolean synchronously before the re-render (for whatever reason). Not why it happened but how can we make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={buttonHandler} type="button">
       {isLoading ? "True" ; "False"}
      </button>
```

We use a Ternary operator

```
condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

in useSate hook the setSate is asynchronous. You can use the console.log() outer of buttonHandler. You will see the value will be updated. As asynchronous nature, you are not seeing the updated result.