# React useState and setState behave wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been testing the change of states to be able to depend on them and calculate others but I have several results depending on the implementation, and there is one in particular that I do not know or have no idea of what is happening or why it gives that result, pay attention to the console.log()

case: 1

```
const [state, setState] = useState({count: 0});

const handleCount = () => {
    console.log(state); // prints {count: 0}
    setState(prevState => {
      prevState.count = prevState.count + 1;
      return prevState;
    });
    console.log(state); // prints {count: 1}
  }

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('has changed.. ' + state.count)
  }, [state]); // in this case this doesn't show any changes, so isn't renders anything, I need to render this value

// in render
<Button onClick={() => handleCount()}>
   Click {state.count}
</Button>
```

case: 2

```
const handleCount = () => {
    console.log(state); // prints {count: 0}
    setStateV(prevState => ({...prevState, count: prevState.count + 1}));
    console.log(state); // prints {count: 0}
  }

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('has changed.. ' + state.count)
  }, [state]); // it show that changed, but I cant depend on this because it haven't changed when I needed it
```

case: 3

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0);
const handleCount = () => {
  console.log(state); // prints 0
  setState(state => state + 1);
  console.log(state); // prints 0 it supposed to be 1!
}
```

I have read [this](https://ozmoroz.com/2018/11/why-my-setstate-doesnt-work/) but not worked at all

So, I need help to understand what is going on please...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functional `setState` doesn't have **callback** function option (which is available in [this.setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of class component) because it has `useEffect`. Try this and check the console logs:

```
const handleCount = () => {
  console.log('initial state', state) // prints {count: 0}
  setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, count: prevState.count + 1 }))
  console.log(
    'state after Calling Async seState might not print latest state',
    state
  ) // prints {count: 0}
}


useEffect(() => {
  console.debug('state changed', state)
  // first print: { count: 0 } at mount
  // second print: { count: 1 }
}, [state])
```

Answer (score 1):

React uses `Object.is` to compare the state object `{count: 0}` in your case. In first case you are just mutating the property count and returning the same object. That's why react thinks that state has not changed.Try the snippet bellow

```js
const myObj = { count: 0};
myObj.count = 3;

console.log(Object.is(myObj, myObj)); // returns true
```

But if you want to use an object inside `useState()`, when you make an update to the state you should always return a new object with `Object.assign` or by just simply destructuring the prevState object like this.

```
const handleCount = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
         // if using Object.assign
         // return Object.assign(prevState, {count: prevState.count + 1})
         return {...prevState, count: prevState.count + 1}
    });
  }
```

Or for a simple count variable you can just use

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const handleCount = () => {
  setCount(prevCount => (prevCount + 1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're mutating the prevState argument which is giving you wrong results, try following:

```js
setState(prevState => {
  const count = prevState.count + 1
  return { ...prevState, count }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const handleCount = () => {
    console.log(state);
    setState({...state, count: (state.count + 1)});
    console.log(state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up state between functional component and class component. Clear concept is Functional Component does not have any state but it has `useState` hooks. for example:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({count: 0});
```

Though you used state for `userState` but here state is just a variable. You could have use like below:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState({count: 0});
```

On the other hand, for class component you have to use state that is like

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {count: 0}
}
```

Where you can set the state object like

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {count: prevState.count+1}
});
```

Please the below two example for **Functional Component and Class Component**

**Functional Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function Example() {

    const [state, setState] = useState({count: 0});

    const handleCount = () => {
        console.log(state); // prints {count: 0}
        setState({count: state.count+1});
        console.log(state); // prints {count: 1}
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('has changed.. ' + state.count)
    }, [state]);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleCount()}>
                Click {state.count}
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Class Component**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Example extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {count: 0}
    }

    handleCount = () => {
        console.log(this.state); // prints {count: 0}
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {count: prevState.count+1}
        });
        console.log(this.state); // prints {count: 1}
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleCount()}>
                    Click {this.state.count}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```