# Can't display elements of array React

Tags: reactjs

I can see my array in state, but I don't know why elements of array doesn't display on the app interface.

```
const [members, setMembers] = useState([])

useEffect( () => {
    getMembers();
}, [props.event])



const getMembers = () => {
    let new_members = [];
    console.log(props.event)
    props.event &&  props.event.uczestnicy.map(member => {
        member.get().then(doc => {
            let new_member;
            new_member = {
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id
            }
            new_members.push(new_member)
        })
        setMembers(new_members)
    })
    console.log(new_members)
    console.log(members)    
}
```

[...]

```
{members && members.map(member => {
    console.log('mem',member)
    return(
        <div key={member.id}>
            {member.nick}
        </div>
    )
})}
```

[image]

So I can see this array in Components using React Developer Tools, but even `console.log` doesn't see it in the moment of performing.

And console.log(new_members) and console.log(members) result :
[image]

Comment: You need to wait for the promis to resolve before trying to use it.

Comment: Ok, but how can I do it ? and why then console display `new_members` but `members ` doesn't ?

Comment: The first log displays the values because they are set. But `setMembers` requires another render before the `members` are actually set and the log statement is ofc executed within the same render so it is still unset in that moment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state) I know you're using `useState` hook, but the concept of react lifecycle is identical. This question is asked almost daily, please search to see if your issue has already been asked and has an accepted solution.

Comment: Also, you've no asynchronous code so each iteration of array::map updates state with the same initial empty `newMembers` array.

Comment: Ok. I added async. And now I understand why console.log() doesn't work. But I still don't understand why this array doesn't display in application interface... Maybe it will be easier if I give you all component code - https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-brook-bhs7v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Just `.map()` doesn't show this array, but I see in React Developer Tools that this array is there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your member values are fetch asynchronously, so its ideal if you set state only after all the values are resolved. For this you can use a `Promise.all`

```
const getMembers = async () => {
    let new_members = [];
    console.log(props.event)
    if(props.event) {
      const val  = await Promise.all(props.event.uczestnicy.map(member => {
        return member.get().then(doc => {
            let new_member;
            new_member = {
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id
            }
            return new_member
        })
     });
     setMembers(values);
     console.log(values);
   } 
}
```