# react setState is not working when I try to change page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand what am doing wrong here, couldn't find any solutions.
I hope you can help me.

I guess `setState` in `onChange` function is not working or maybe another problem here.
I've tried everything to understand the problem but i couldnt'.

I am using ant design pagination to change the pages. thank you.

```js
      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
          loading: true,
        });
        const endpoint = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=${this.state.currentPage}`;
        this.getData(endpoint);
      }
    
      getData = (endpoint) => {
        axios.get(endpoint).then((res) => {
          this.setState({
            movies: res.data.results,
            mainImg: res.data.results[0].poster_path,
            loading: false,
            currentPage: res.data.page,
            totalPages: res.data.total_pages,
          });
          console.log(res);
          
        });
      };
    
      onChange = (page) => {
        let endpoint = "";        
        this.setState({ loading: true, currentPage: page });    
        endpoint = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=${this.state.currentPage}`;    
        this.getData(endpoint);
      };
    
      render() {
        const { totalPages, currentPage, movies } = this.state;
        return (
          <div className="main-content">
            <h1>home component</h1>
            <div>
              {movies.map((movie) => {
                return (
                  <ul key={movie.id}>
                    <li>{movie.title}</li>
                  </ul>
                );
              })}
            </div>
            <div>
              <Pagination
                defaultCurrent={1}
                total={totalPages}
                current={currentPage}
                showSizeChanger={false}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: What exacrly isn't working or what error do you get?

Comment: there is no error, when i click a number on pagination to change page. page and loading is not changing. setstate in onChange is not working, doesnt change loading and currentpage

Comment: Try logging `page` as the first statement in your `onChange` function to see if it actually works. Does your `getData()` get any response? You should investigate where precisely the issue is.

Comment: i've tried that,yes page is working fine page number is changing when i press.
 yes my getdata get response but only first page no : 1

Comment: Allright, so it's an issue with your backend, not React. Just investigate the `getData()` and your browser console to be sure.

Comment: no :) currentPage is always 1. this.setState({ loading: true, currentPage: page }); this is not working

Comment: It's not possible that `setState` is not working, it must be an issue with this `Pagination` component. Maybe you're using it wrong, read the docs or something...

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous

[React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

In your onChange function, use **page** instead of **this.state.currentPage** when you update your endpoint variable (since state has not yet been updated)

Then, end your onChange function with **this.render();** to re-render your JSX once the state variable has been updated

Comment: thanks a lot i solved this way ->

onChange = (page) => {
    let endpoint = "";

    this.setState({ loading: true, currentPage: page }, () => {
      //console.log(this.state.currentPage);
      endpoint = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=${this.state.currentPage}`;

      this.getData(endpoint);
    });
  };