# useEffect is not getting call first time when parent state is changed by child state at

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Child component

```
export const FlightRange = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type='range'
        min={1000}
        max={50000}
        step="500"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value);
          props.handleSliderChange(value);
        }}
      />
      <span>{value}</span>

    </>
  );
};
```

parent component

```
useEffect(() => {
    const result = axios.get('http://localhost:8000/')
    .then((res) => res.json())

    .then((data) => {
      const flightData = data.filter((value) => {
        return (
          valuesplit(' ')[1] < priceSlider
        );
      });
    })
  }, [priceSlider]);

return(
    <Child value={priceSlider} handleSliderChange={(value)=> setPriceSlider(value)} />
 )
```

useEffect does not get called when the slider is changed the first time. It gets called a second time with the stale (previous value) value.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `onChange` you need to call like this

```
onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value);
          props.handleSliderChange(e.target.value);
        }}
```

since value is not updated instantly when you call `setValue(e.target.value);` , `value` will have previous value that you are passing in `props.handleSliderChang(value)` 
to know how `setState` works see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41446620/7784354)

Comment: What if I have multiple form elements in a child element. Whenever each element change how can I trigger the parent element in the same render cycle
`const [journeyInfo, setJourneyInfo] = useState({
    source: props.journeyInfo.source
}

<Input
        type='text'
        value={journeyInfo.source}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setJourneyInfo({ ...journeyInfo, source: e.target.value })
        }
      />
     <Button onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.handleFormInfo(journeyInfo);
      }}>`

Comment: instead of creating states in child and parent just create state in parent and pass down to child and `onChange` update the state of parent, here i can see you have created `value` and `priceSlider` , you can use `priceSlider` in child as well, no need to create same state in child

Comment: like the following

Comment: `<Child value={[priceSlider,setPriceSlider]} />`

Comment: `const [value, setValue] = props.value`;

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on the `onClick` callback of `FlightRange` `input`, see comments on code below

```
onChange = {(e) => {
  setValue(e.target.value); // this is async

  // therefore, the value you are passing here is not the same as e.target.value but simply the value before setting the state
  props.handleSliderChange(value);  
}}
```

So to fix this just refactor `props.handleSliderChange` argument to `e.target.value`

```
onChange = {(e) => {
  setValue(e.target.value);
  props.handleSliderChange(e.target.value);  
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It because the child is having it's own life cycle since you are using `useState` in child. so whatever props you pass to your child, the child's state won't affected.

plus you are passing incorrect value in `onChange`

**Solution:** just use the props value directly on child (do not store in state):

```
export const FlightRange = (props) => {
  const { value, handleSliderChange } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type='range'
        min={1000}
        max={50000}
        step="500"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleSliderChange(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <span>{value}</span>

    </>
  );
};
```