# cannot set state inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I can see response object containing array of users , but it seems setState doesn't work inside `useEffect()` hook.

This is request code.

```
     const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);
     const getUsers=async()=>{
         await axios.get(API_URL,{
             headers:{
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                     'Accept': 'application/json',
                     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
             }
         })
         .then((res)=>{
            const data = res.data.users;
             console.log(data);
            setUsers([...users,data]);
            console.log(users);
            
         })
         .catch((err)=>{
             console.log(err);
         })
     }
     useEffect(()=>{
         
         getUsers();
     },[])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setUsers()` is the asynchronous method, and you can't get the updated value of `users` immediately after `setusers()`.

```
setUsers([...users,data]);
console.log(users); // This will console old value of users
```

You should use `useEffect` with adding a `users` dependency to check the updated value of `users`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(users);
}, [users]);
```

Comment: Thank you @WilliamWang for your response.

Comment: When 'users' is passed in dependency array of useEffect() i get more number of users than i actually have

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    
    getUsers();
  }, [users])
 `

Comment: no, just add one more useEffect to console.log. you should do getUsers() in the useEffect with no dependency.

Comment: Now I am able to get users array but cannot access its properties eg, `users.forEach((user)=>console.log(user))` produces array of users, but  `users.forEach((user)=>console.log(user.firstname))` prints undefined.