# React 17.0.1 basic onChange is not updating values into state

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have simple form where onChange value is updated as typed.

Example when type 12, only 1 is saved in the state and when type second time 123 only 12 is stored.

useState :

```
const [costsFormValues, setCostsFormValues] = useState({});
```

Function

```
const handleCostInputValues = (event, index) => {
    setCostsFormValues({
        ...costsFormValues,
        [event.target.name]: [event.target.value],
    });
    console.log(costsFormValues) //prints only 1 instead of 12
}
```

Form

```
<Form.Control type="number" onChange={e => handleCostInputValues(e, i)} />
```

Comment: how do i fix it ?

Comment: it shows the values typed, which is 12 - only in the state it is saved as 1

Comment: @AheetShah It's more about closures. You literally cannot access the new value from the current closure.

Comment: @JanezKuhar I think this question is about async nature of State Setter functions; Not related to closures.

Comment: @DeepakMurthy You may also want to see [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710), [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41446560/2873538), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/2873538), [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).