# React - Adding new parameters to useState inside of useEffect is delayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on a project of mine and ran into an issue. So I am adding "sorting" to my products. So for instance, you can sort "hoodies" based on color, brand, size etc. Fortunately, the API I am using accepts these values, such as: `brand: <brand>` or `base_colour: <color>`.

So far, I have managed to get the key & value to the API, but it is acting a bit strange.

Whenever I sort the products, it doesn't instantly apply. So for instance, if I want to sort the "brand" to "bike", nothing happens. But if I then try to sort the "color" to "black". Then the brand changes, but not the color. So it is "delayed" by one.

Through my debugging of this issue, I am 80% sure my `useEffect` is the thief here.

Here is a picture that might help:

[image]

As you can see, the key and value of `attribute_1046` gets sent to my API fetch js file, but it doesn't get added to the parameters. But whenever I change the brand (Meaning, I have 2 sortings). Then the `attribute_1046` gets added to the parameters.

Here is my API Fetch code:

```
  // Receiving the Key and Value when a user interacts with the "sorting" dropdowns.
  let facetValue = props.facetValue;
  let facetKey = props.facetKey;

  // Setting initial parameters
  const [params, setParams] = useState({
    store: "US",
    offset: props.offset,
    categoryId: props.categoryId,
    limit: props.limit,
    country: "US",
    sort: "freshness",
    currency: "USD",
    sizeSchema: "US",
    lang: "en-US",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // if FacetKey is not undefined.
    if (facetKey) {
      console.log(`${facetKey}: ${facetValue}`);
      setParams({
        [facetKey]: facetValue,
        ...params,
      });
    }
    console.log(params);

    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://asos2.p.rapidapi.com/products/v2/list",
      params: params,
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "",
      },
    };
    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        setProducts(response.data.products);
        props.items(response.data.itemCount);
        props.facets(response.data.facets);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
    // Is it my dependencies that are incorrect?
  }, [props.limit, facetKey]);
```

Not sure if this file is needed as well, but here the user sort the products:

```
  const [facets, setFacets] = useState();
  const [facetValue, setFacetValue] = useState();
  const [facetKey, setFacetKey] = useState();

        <BottomBar>
          <div className={classes.filter_grid_container}>
            {facets != null
              ? facets.map((filter) => (
                  <div className={classes.item}>
                    {filter.name != "Price Range" ? (
                      <Dropdown
                        name={filter.name}
                        values={filter.facetValues}
                        facetKey={filter.id}
                        facetValue={(facetValue) => setFacetValue(facetValue)}
                        facetItemKey={(facetKey) => setFacetKey(facetKey)}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <DropdownPrice />
                    )}
                  </div>
                ))
              : null}
          </div>
        </BottomBar>
      </StyledApp>
      <div className={classes.grid_container}>
        <FetchAPI
          limit={limit}
          offset={offset}
          items={(itemCount) => setItemCount(itemCount)}
          categoryId={params.id}
          facets={(facets) => setFacets(facets)}
          facetValue={facetValue}
          facetKey={facetKey}
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: setState is asynchronous, and a state value is constant throughout a single render, so logging right after calling setState will always show the state value in the *current* render, the updated value won't be available until the next render cycle. see: [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually issue is function returned by `useState` is asynchronous and you  are updating `params` in useEffect and immedially access it to pass in request of axios api.

**Issue**:-

```js
    if (facetKey) {
      console.log(`${facetKey}: ${facetValue}`);
      setParams({
        [facetKey]: facetValue,  // updating params here
        ...params,
      });
    }
    console.log(params);

    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://asos2.p.rapidapi.com/products/v2/list",
      params: params,  // using it here so this will always return previous value
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "",
      },
    };
```

**Solution**:-

```js
    let requestParam = {};
    if (facetKey) {
      requestParam = {[facetKey]: facetValue, ...params}   // create const with expected value
      setParams({...requestParam});
    }

    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://asos2.p.rapidapi.com/products/v2/list",
      params: requestParam,   // pass new const here in options
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "",
      },
    };
```

Comment: Ah okay, I see. Gave this a try but getting that `requestParams` is not defined. Did you not get that error or? Posted on pastebin: `7nPbf5hW`

Comment: My bad, I had declated `requestParam` in if block and was trying to access it outside if block. I have update my answer and by default I have declared `requestParam` with empty object if you are required to pass default `params` value in option then you can declare it like `let requestParam = {...params}`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because inside your `useEffect`, whenever you call `setParams`, it doesn't occur in synchronous mode. `setParams` is async in nature, so in case you want to call an `api` on change on `params`, you can do following.

Also, as a suggestion, if you could check the way `setParams` is being called, this way it would be less error prone as it will not batch updates. It is generally better to use the functional convention of `setState` whenever your next state depends on your previous state.

```js
// Receiving the Key and Value when a user interacts with the "sorting" dropdowns.
const facetValue = props.facetValue;
const facetKey = props.facetKey;

// Setting initial parameters
const [params, setParams] = useState({
  store: "US",
  offset: props.offset,
  categoryId: props.categoryId,
  limit: props.limit,
  country: "US",
  sort: "freshness",
  currency: "USD",
  sizeSchema: "US",
  lang: "en-US",
});

useEffect(() => {
  // if FacetKey is not undefined.
  if (facetKey) {
    console.log(`${facetKey}: ${facetValue}`);
    setParams((currParams) => { ...currParams, [facetKey]: facetValue });
  }

  // Is it my dependencies that are incorrect?
}, [props.limit, facetKey]);



useEffect(() => {
  // you can move your api call to a function itself which takes params
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://asos2.p.rapidapi.com/products/v2/list",
    params: params,
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-key": "",
      "x-rapidapi-host": "",
    },
  };
  axios
    .request(options)
    .then(function (response) {
      setProducts(response.data.products);
      // assuming here that props.items is more like props.setItems as you are setting it's value
      props.items(response.data.itemCount);
      // assuming here that props.facets is more like props.setFacets as you are setting it's value
      props.facets(response.data.facets);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
}, [params]);
```