# My react state is not changing on select change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-state

I'm trying to change my react state depending on the selected item from my select element,
this is my react State :

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState('');
```

This is my OnChange function :

```
const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
      console.log('this is the target value',event.target.value);
      setSelectedItem('hello');
      console.log(selectedItem);
    };
```

And this is my select element (I'm using the MaterialUI select component) :

```
<Select autoFous
        onChange={handleSelectChange}
        >
            <MenuItem value='simpleClick'>             
            Simple Click
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='seleniumClick'>             
            selenium click
            </MenuItem>
        </Select>
```

What am I doing wrong so my state is not chaning ?

Comment: The state value in any given render does not change. setState is asynchronous and the updated value won't be available until the next render cycle. Does this answer your question? [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Comment: try onClick instead of onChange. I should Work

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't change instantly value when you use `setSelectedItem`
You can check the changed value after `setSelectedItem` triggers rerender.

So after you do `setSelectedItem('Hello')` it will trigger rerender and `selectedItem` will be changed to `'Hello'` on the next render cycle.