# React js useState array does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm having trouble with the code given under. I want to add a new task object to my array, so firstly i try to find the max id in the tasks array and i give the maxId+1 to my new object as id.
Then i try to append my new Task object at the end, but data is not updated after i call setTasks.

Any helps would be appreciated

```js
  const[tasks,setTasks] = useState([
    {
        id:1,
        text:"Task1",
        day:"21.06.2021",
        reminder : true
    },
    {
        id:2,
        text:"Task2",
        day:"21.06.2021",
        reminder : false
    },
    {
        id:3,
        text:"Task3",
        day:"22.06.2021",
        reminder : true
    }

  ])

  const addTask = (task) => {
    var id = 0
    for (const t of tasks){
      if (t.id > id){
        id = t.id+1
      }
    }
    console.log("Before",tasks)
    const newTask = {id, ...task}
    setTasks([...tasks, newTask])
    console.log("After",tasks)
  }
```

Comment: Hi! That code to update it looks just fine, the problem must be elsewhere. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: The code seems good.

Comment: Can you include a codesandbox link?  The tasks state isn't going to have its updated value until the next render.

Comment: I think you need to read how the state works in general, you won't be able to observe the updated state just one line after setting it.

Comment: This will work, but as mentioned by @ilkerkaran, you won't see the change in your `console.log` as setting React state happens asynchronously and will not be complete before the `log` runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the normal behaviour in React. When `setTasks` is triggered inside the handler, `tasks` yet has the old value, even after setTasks is triggered. But, when component is refreshed, if you use an useEffect, you see, now the value is refreshed. Bellow a simple example with update array and console.log print the state:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-fast-q2yxn?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  /**
   * component state:
   */
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  /**
   * handler:
   */
  const addItemToArray = () => {
    setArray((a) => [...a, count]);
    setCount((c) => c + 1);
    console.log("inside handler: ", array);
  };
  /**
   * useEffect:
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("inside useEffect: ", array);
  }, [array]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addItemToArray}>Add Item to Array</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If this is the answer, then it's an obvious duplicate of [this often-asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state).