# React unable to pass state from one page to another

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

so I am attempting to pass data to another state in React.
Here's what happens -> on page load I grab my books from Google Books API
I have the array of that book's data.  I am trying to set the state of 4 things based off the data in the array. This is where I'm having trouble, it's not updating the state, and sometimes the Bookdetails page isn't grabbing it. Here is my main page function:

```
const viewBookDetails =  bookNumber => props => {
 //   setBookID({ bookID: bookNumber });
    console.log("Test test test");
    console.log(coryBooks[bookNumber]);
    setState({ title: coryBooks[bookNumber].volumeInfo.title, author: coryBooks[bookNumber].volumeInfo.author  });
    setState({ img: coryBooks[bookNumber].volumeInfo.img });
    setState({ publisher: coryBooks[bookNumber].volumeInfo.publisher });

    setState ({
        publisher: "test"
    });

    console.log("state: ",state);
    history.push({
        pathname: '/Bookdetails',
        state 
    });

};
```

when I console.log it, it says the data is "". Sometimes, and I mean completely randomly, sometimes the other page will get the data correct, and it updates accordingly, but I have no idea why. Here is my other page:

```
import '../App.css';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Milestone1part2 from './Milestone1part2';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { useHistory, context, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";


const Bookdetails = props => {
    const { title, author, img, publisher } =
        (props.location && props.location.state);
    const history = useHistory();


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(title);
        console.log(history.location.state);
    }, []);


    return (
        <div>
            <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">
                Go Back
      </NavLink>
            <div className="form-details">
                <div>
                    <strong>Publisher:</strong> {publisher}
                </div>
               
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Bookdetails;
```

edit 2: here is the code for my button which sends an int for the book number and calls the function "viewBookDetails"

```
{coryBooks.map(function (item, i) {
                        return <tr key={'item-' + i}> <td>{item.volumeInfo.title}</td><td> <a href={item.volumeInfo.previewLink}> <img src={item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail} alt="image" /> </a>
                            <button type="submit" onClick={viewBookDetails(i) } > Book details </button> </td> </tr>
                    })}
```

edit: here is my entire main page code, SO editor giving me a hard
time for formatting it here.  https://pastebin.com/4VD8JqFn

Is there a better way to pass data between pages besides history? Why
is my state not updating?

I have been ripping my hair out over this problem, any help is
appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Comment: @ggorlen maybe for the reason as to why it's not logging the correct thing, but my other page is also not getting the proper state, except for sometimes. I think the problem is using history to pass the data.

Comment: Right, there are multiple problems. State is purely internal to a component, so passing one component's state to another one is grounds for chaos, I'd imagine. Try unpacking the relevant primitives and pieces of data not controlled by React into props so there's no aliasing. I'd have to see a bit more code ([mcve]) and context to help more concretely than this though.

Comment: Based on this syntax, I'm seeing a merging of a factory function, a react pure component, as well as a react class based component. `const viewBookDetails =  bookNumber => props => { ... setState }`. This will likely cause issues. Could you please include the entire file where this is defined, as well as where and how `viewBookDetails` is used.

Comment: @ggorlen I updated with all the code from that page. The page number and such is not a problem, and is getting passed appropriately. It's literally just a function called from a button that passed an int for book number.

Comment: Have you tried passing as params? via the useParams hook?

Comment: @FujiRoyale I'll look into this. Thank you