# After updating state, UI is reflecting correctly, but console.log shows state is not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Within `handleClick` function, after I click a cell, `squares` state gets updated through `setSquares(copiedSquares)` then I console.log `squares` to see if state has been updated properly. Strange thing is after my first click in the cell, I see the 'X' shows up in the cell as expected, but console.logging square state shows still empty! But UI is based on `squares` state so this is confusing to me. After I click for 2nd time in different cell then state `squares` shows previous state so it's one step behind. So `getWinner()` function is not working properly due to this behaviour. Can anybody explain why this is happening?
https://codesandbox.io/s/tic-tac-toe-practice-kvun2d?file=/src/App.js:0-1709

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Game() {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(""));
  const [playerTurn, setPlayerTurn] = useState("X");
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState("");

  let winningCondition = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
  ];

  const getWinner = () => {
    winningCondition.forEach((arr) => {
      if (
        squares[arr[0]] === "" ||
        squares[arr[1]] === "" ||
        squares[arr[2]] === ""
      ) {
        return;
      } else if (
        squares[arr[0]] === squares[arr[1]] &&
        squares[arr[1]] === squares[arr[2]]
      ) {
        setWinner(squares[arr[0]]);
        console.log("You Win!");
      }
    });
  };

  const handleClick = (idx) => {
    let copiedSquares = [...squares];
    if (playerTurn === "X") {
      copiedSquares[idx] = "X";
      setPlayerTurn("O");
    } else {
      copiedSquares[idx] = "O";
      setPlayerTurn("X");
    }
    setSquares(copiedSquares);
    console.log(squares); // array is empty!
    getWinner();
  };

  function Square({ idx }) {
    return <td onClick={() => handleClick(idx)}>{squares[idx]}</td>;
  }

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <Square idx={0}></Square>
          <Square idx={1}></Square>
          <Square idx={2}></Square>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <Square idx={3}></Square>
          <Square idx={4}></Square>
          <Square idx={5}></Square>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <Square idx={6}></Square>
          <Square idx={7}></Square>
          <Square idx={8}></Square>
        </tr>
        {winner && <p>Winner is {winner}</p>}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41446620/13583510

Comment: When setting state, I used copiedSquares instead of original squares state and now it works fine. I think I heard this before where never directly update the state.