# How to print updated state value in React Native

Tags: react-native

```
const filteredata=  basketdata.filter(obj => {
    return obj.id !== item.id;
});
setBasket([...filteredata]);
console.log('basketdata',basketdata);
```

I am removing items from my array when same items available. After removing item trying to print the array in console but it doesn't printing the actual value. Also I know that `setState()` will not update immediately.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `useEffect`-hook to listen for changes to the variable

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('basketdata',basketdata);
}, [basketdata]);
```

Comment: its rendering the page again

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was filter function does not change the original array it **returns a new array** thats why when you were printing the **basketdata** it was showing all the item.

**Solution:**
print the filteredata in the console log.

```
const filteredata = basketdata.filter((obj) => {
      return obj.id != item.id;
    });
    setBasket([...filteredata]);
    // console.log("basketdata", basketdata); // don't print this
    console.log("filteredata", filteredata);// print this
```