# React useState is 1 step behind the real value of the variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I know that it's repeat, but i don't understand how to fix it in my case
I send put request to server, but it has old value, what i should do?

React code:

```
const [sizeValue, setSizeValue] = useState(basketItem.clotheSize)
```

```
<select
   name={"size"}
   className={"sizeSelector"}
   value={sizeValue}
   onChange={e => {
      setSizeValue(e.target.value)
      updateClothesSize(basketItem.id, sizeValue)
   }}
>
  <option value="s">s</option>
  <option value="m">m</option>
  <option value="l">l</option>
  <option value="xl">xl</option>
  <option value="xxl">xxl</option>
</select>
```

axios code:

```
export const updateClothesSize = async (id, size) => {
    const {data} = await $host.put('api/basket/' + id, {clothesSize: size})
    return data
}
```

Comment: `setSizeValue` *does not* immediately change the value of `sizeValue` in the context which it is called. Instead, it triggers a re-render where the new value of `sizeValue` is available. Just use `e.target.value` or use a `useEffect` separately.

Comment: Just use e.target.value in update cloth size

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/41446560/1441

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useState` will not update the state value immediately. You can fix your issue by either directly passing the value to `updateClothesSize(basketItem.id, e.target.value)`.Or use a useEffect in which you'll call `updateClothesSize`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  updateClothesSize(basketItem.id, sizeValue)
},[sizeValue])
```