# React: Two way binding and value update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've created an input form that takes a value from users. After a button-click, the input field is cleaned. My implementation is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const initialValue = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"];

const Children = () => {
  const [enteredInputChildren, setEnteredInputChildren] = useState("");
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState(initialValue);

  const AddValueChildrenHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setInputList((prevList) => {
      return [...prevList, enteredInputChildren];
    });
    setEnteredInputChildren("");
    console.log(enteredInputChildren);
  };

  const InputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredInputChildren(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.children_dev}>
      <h3>Children component</h3>
      <ul className={classes.list}>
        {inputList.map((item) => {
          return <li key={Math.random().toString()}>{item}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
      <form onSubmit={AddValueChildrenHandler}>
        <input value={enteredInputChildren} onChange={InputChangeHandler} />
        <button type="submit">Add a value</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see above, the value of the variable **enteredInputChildren** is set to an empty string after `setInputList(...)`. However, the output of the line `console.log(enteredInputChildren)` is not an empty string but the user input (what I expect is an empty string).

My question is why is the value of the variable **enteredInputChildren** getting updated after the button-click instead of during the function `AddValueChildrenHandler` call?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're confused about how react `setState` works. This question is asked a few dozen times a week on Stackoverflow [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)