# Why do I get an empty array back, trying to read data from firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a simple todo crud app. I just cannot seem to get my data to be put out on the screen.

```
const Home = () => {

  const [todos,setTodos] = useState([]);

  const getTodos = async () =>{
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "todos"));
    
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {        
      setTodos([...todos,doc.data()])
      console.log(doc.data())
      console.log(todos)
    });  
  }

  useEffect(()=>{  
    getTodos();    
  },[])

  return (    
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}
```

Now the console.log(doc.data()) shows every dataset alright, but the todos array either gets just the first value assigned or returns an empty array.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State setter operations are *asynchronous*, calling `setTodos` doesn't change what's in the array your `todos` variable points to. Instead, it schedules a new call to your component function in which you'll get the new data from `useState`. (More in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state).) That's why both your `console.log(todos)` and your repeated calls to `setTodos` aren't working: Both are using *outdated* information from `todos`.

When setting state based on existing state (your current array), it's usually best to use the callback form of the state setter. So the minimal change would be:

```
// But keep reading!
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {        
    setTodos((todos) => [...todos, doc.data()]);
});
```

That would work, but rather than calling `setTodos` in a loop, you might want to do the loop and then call the setter once when you're done.

I don't use Firebase, but [Nick Parsons found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76834386/why-do-i-get-an-empty-array-back-trying-to-read-data-from-firebase/76834484?noredirect=1#comment135454668_76834484) and posted [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot.md#querysnapshotdocs) saying you can get the docs as an array via a `docs` property. So you can call `map` on that array:

```
setTodos((todos) => [...todos, ...querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data())]);
```

Comment: Glad to see that you're back :) - I don't use firebase either, so don't quote me on this, but from my limited usage of it in the past, I believe you have to use `querySnapshot.docs.map(...)`, as the QuerySnaphhot itself that you get back from `getDocs()` doesn't seem to have a `.map()` method, but it has a [`.docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot.md#querysnapshotdocs) property which represents an array.

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons! I couldn't find those docs, appreciate the link! (And the welcome. :-) )

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm and I was trying to get my head around it since yesterday! Just if you have time and patience to answer: Just so I get this right - if I call a method, which is setting the state of something, it is automatically rerendering the component? Makes sense so far, just to keep everything up to date. But I dont get exactly how using a callback is making a difference..thank you so much!

Comment: @jungs - Yes, setting state schedules a call to re-render the component. The difference with using a callback is covered in the React docs [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - thank you so much for your time! To anybody else having this kind of issue: I set the state outside of the loop. Otherwise it gave me everything back twice, but now it is working finally...

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `setTodos([...todos,doc.data()])`

try this

```js
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {        
      setTodos((prev) => [...prev, doc.data()])
      console.log(doc.data())
      console.log(todos)
    });
```

Comment: And remove the `console.log(todos)`, since it will only show outdated information, because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, true, i just didnt bother to change that