# Updating the state to the current target.value of a click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some trouble here on a simple dropdown select from MaterialUI/React that although I am able to update the label for the item I am clicking on, the state is still stuck on the previous value. Open the console terminal to see what I mean.

This will/can create issues when I want another set of options to open depeding on the state selected. For example, if I click on "Blues & Jazz", I should be able to get a set of options that correspond to subgenres of "Blues & Jazz), not subgenres of whatever else was clicked before.

For brevity, I didn't add the submenus options. I can probably handle that if I can get the state to update `onclick`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, FormControl, MenuItem, Select } from "@mui/material";

export const wbrselectors = {
  sections: ["Rock", "Soul", "Hip Hop & R&B", "Blues & Jazz", "Classical"]
};

export default function App() {
  const [sectionone, setSectionOne] = useState("Rock");

  const onSectionOneSelectChange = ({ target }) => {
    const value = target.value;

    setSectionOne(value);

    console.log("value:", value, ", sectionone:", sectionone);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <FormControl fullWidth size="small">
        <Select
          component="dropdown"
          value={sectionone}
          name="sections"
          defaultValue=""
          onChange={onSectionOneSelectChange}
        >
          {wbrselectors.sections.map((item, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={index} value={item}>
              {item}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Here's a link in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-bessie-pcg587?file=/src/App.js:0-959).

Comment: Your `console.log` won't show the new value (setting state is asynchronous, and `sectionone` won't have changed yet), but this looks like showing any additional `select` components based on that state should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately

Answer (score 0):

Setting state is async. You need to use another hook to react upon the changes on state:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("sectionone:", sectionone);
  }, [sectionone]);
```

Here, the function we provide to `useEffect` hook will run when `sectionone` changes.

Comment: But this is jsut a console log. I can't put the onclick event fucntion in here because it reads from the event.target.value, which I would have to inject here. I only want to update my state onclick.

Comment: @LOTUSMS I don't quite understand your comment. You'll keep the `onclick` callback, and add `useEffect` separately. You are not going to put the `onclick` callback in `useEffect`.

Comment: I updated the sandbox with the subgenres to visualize it better

Comment: The function callback for updating the value on a click event contains event.target.value as an argument that needs to be passed into the callback. I cant do that inside the useEffect. I dont have visibility from useEfect into one specific click event. And I will have several

Comment: @LOTUSMS The quick and dirty solution is just to use `value` instead of `sectionone` in your `data.find()`

Comment: @DBS THAT DID IT!!!! Thank you! Post an actual answer so I can credit you

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working as expected, the state update is async in nature, and React might batch multiple `setState()` updates for better performance.