# Was javascript Always Asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Does anybody know if javascript always fully asynchronous ever since it's birth? When did it begin to be fully asynchronous?

Comment: it's not fully asynchronous at all ... the asynchronous bits are asyncrhonous

Comment: @JaromandaX asynch just means that the flow of events don't happen at the same time. all functions in javascript are asynch. im pretty sure u're confusing it with parallel, which javascript is not.

Comment: no, I'm pretty sure you don't understand javascript because you say `all functions in javascript are asynch` this is absolutely wrong

Comment: @rbtLong You're still dead wrong...

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande i found the answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous