# How to make a line wait for function return

Tags: javascript

I have 2 files

```
//init.js
var x = getMasterList(location);
console.log(x);
console.log("should have printed list");
```

And

```
//read.js
function getMasterList(location) {
    var list = [];
   ref.child(company).child("listOfLocations").once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var item = childSnapshot.val();
          list.push(item);
        })
    });
    console.log("In function");
    return list;
}
```

The console's output is

```
undefined
should have printed list
In function
```

The problem is, because of javascript's asynchronous nature, it prints out 'x' before assigning it. I've looked at promises and it doesn't seem like it can help me since it didn't change the async behaviour. I've also looked at callbacks and I can't seem to make them work for multiple files.

Any ways of getting around this so that it only prints after 'x' has a value?

Comment: You need to learn how to use promises or callbacks.  What don't you understand?

Comment: In JS, to use asychronous functions, use callbacks, promises, or async/await

Comment: This is not supposed to happen with the code you provided. Please provide the exact code that you used. JS is synchronous unless you explicitly tell it to invoke a function asynchronously.

Comment: I think we're guessing //do stuff contains something async

Comment: Promises don't work, the output is the same. Can you use callbacks when a function is in another file?

Comment: _"because of javascript's asynchronous nature"_ -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/32456239/402037

Comment: @Astrodude: That means you're using them wrong.  Yes; files don't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), you can achieve this quite easily.

**read.js**

```
function getMasterList(location, callback) {
    var list = [];
    //do stuff
    console.log("In function");
    callback(list);
}
```

**init.js**

```
var x = getMasterList(location, function(x){
    console.log(x);
    console.log("should have printed list");
});
```