# For loop is executed asynchronously in javascript?

Tags: javascript, execution, synchronous

In my example below, why does it log 512, rather than 1?  I understand javascript is synchronous, so shouldn't the logging occur long before the for loop completes?  For this reason, I was expecting result = 1 when logged.

```
let result = 1;
for (counter = 1; counter < 10; counter ++) {
    result = result * 2;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not sure if that's a typo, but re: " I understand javascript is synchronous": it *is* synchronous unless you do something async. That code is synchronous, so the code after the loop won't execute until the loop had finished. Everything would need to be a callback otherwise.

Comment: For the most part, most javascript expressions are sequential (synchronous), including loops. There are some asynchronous methods, such as `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, and `XMLHttpRequest` that are also initiated sequentially, but asynchronously wait for a return or callback.

Comment: Why would you expect that? The loop is executed before the log.

Answer (score 1):

`Synchronous`: Means that only one operation can be in progress at a time.

According to this definition your `console.log()` function will only be executed after your loop has finished executing.

If you want your code to run `console.log()` while executing your loop, you mean your code is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is WHEN are you logging.

When you are logging the content of "result", the for-loop is completed, and the value of the "result" variable have been updated each iterations of the loop.

The following might illustrate this

```
let result = 1;
console.log(result);
console.log("loop start");
for (counter = 1; counter < 10; counter ++) {
    console.log(result);
    result = result * 2;
}
console.log("loop end");
console.log(result);
```

will give you the following result:

```
1
loop start
1
 2
 8
 16
 32
 64
 128
 256
loop end
 512
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript synchronize that's mean is  one thread work so this operation is iterative
you can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous) for more information

regard :)

Comment: Please don't just link to another answer.